# Why are usernames not unique, here on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, display-names

I always thought that each username corresponds to one user. But it seems that multiple users can have the same username. Why is that?

My userprofile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/754705/michael

Another user with the same name: https://stackoverflow.com/users/844808/michael

Shouldn't usernames be unique handles? Otherwise, if I see the same username twice, I can never be sure if it is really the same user, or only some user with the same name. Or is this just an individual case?

Comment: On a site with many millions of users, that's not really practical. The user ID is the unique key; mixups happen exceedingly rarely

Comment: You can be sure by looking at their userid, which is the one thing that's unique. Other than that, there are plenty of people called Michael, so why shouldn't they name themselves like that?

Comment: MSE duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197272/why-is-there-another-user-with-the-same-name-as-mine.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/why-does-stack-overflow-allow-duplicate-display-names on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: because it would annoy the Steves

Comment: Makes sense somehow. In real life, different people can have the same name too. And I usually have no problem in distinguishing between the two Cathy's that I know in real life ;) And @Bart, I think we have discussed in another thread too right? I will go and check to see if the Bart in the other thread has the same user ID as you ;)

Comment: If he was an ass @Michael, that wasn't me .... really ...

Comment: Oh, great, now that I've edited, I'm going to get all of Michael's notifications. I insist that you change your name, Michael.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I'm sooo sorry :-( just kidding ;) The five question marks where there for a reason!! Our names are different, btw.

Comment: Someone should make a data.se query with top username counts

Comment: @PlasmaHH yes yes yes

Comment: @PlasmaHH http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190298/top-display-names-on-stack-overflow

Comment: So "Michael"s are in 6th place, huh?

Comment: @Pekka웃 "On a site with many millions of users, that's not really practical".How about Facebook... With billion of users, user name is unique. And what happen if same username two users comment on a post? When someone use @ username it will go notofication for both users?

Comment: @DamithRuwan Facebook's system is not that different from SO's. There's a display name that can be anything you want, and a unique URL. That @ notifications sometimes reach the wrong user(s) here on SO is a solvable problem that doesn't require introducing unique user names. It's already been solved in SO chat: you get a popup where you can select who exactly you want to talk to. That feature could make it over to SO eventually

Answer (score 15):

Because they don't really need to be. You're not likely to mix yourself up with someone else, and in the unlikely event that you need to differentiate between two users with the same name, there are other identifiers (ie. reputation, profile picture) that help tell people apart.

Also, having your own identity that you actually associate your real-world self with - as opposed to a username that you can hide behind - can help people act in a more civil manner. Maybe I'm a bit hypocritical saying that, but I think the point is still valid. This isn't a forum where users talk about random junk and post spam and bash each other all day, it's a place for *people* to interact with each other and help each other out. People should be themselves, and that includes having their own name.

Comment: People don't act any better when they are forced to use real names. Often they act worse. Facebook groups are a good example of that. Tech companies like to say that real names encourage better behavior, but their real reason for promoting that idea is to be able to map their users' online data with other databases and data scanned from public records.

Answer (score 13):

Pay attention to the user-ids, which are unique (right?):

- You

  https://stackoverflow.com/users/754705/michael
- Evil Michael

  https://stackoverflow.com/users/844808/michael

From now on, I shall call you Michael #754705!

Comment: What are you going to say if Michael 844808 comes and complains that you called him evil?

Answer (score -17):

You could possibly add a number at the end, automatically? Example: The first registered name gets the name without a number, everywhere. All successive registers will be prefixed with a number visible to all, except the user with the successive name.

Comment: I'm not a number.

Comment: And all the cool usernames are already taken.

Comment: All accounts already have numbers, regardless of the name. And those numbers are reasonably visible.

Comment: @MSalters yeah I know that. I was thinking of something like: "Brokenhope". Someone registers that same name. So everyone (except the user) will see "Brokenhope2" or the equivalent. The user would still see their name "Brokenhope", and all users will see the original as the original "Brokenhope".) Was just a thought...