# How do I get a custom Stack Overflow URL?

Tags: support, display-names

Right now my URL is https://stackexchange.com/users/4012123/user3305206.

I want it to be [https://stackexchange.com/users/4012123/[firstname][lastname]](https://stackexchange.com/users/4012123/%5Bfirstname%5D%5Blastname%5D) or something custom like that.

Comment: This actually works now: http://stackexchange.com/users/4012123/firstname_lastname. You can put anything you want after the slash. At least, it will go to the correct place (but then will be redirected to a canonical URL once it gets there).

Comment: Posting meta questions on SO is an indication you don't understand how SO works, and not understanding how it works can get you autoblocked.  Lurk more, read the [help], etc.  Search here for "I can't post anymore questions" and see what can happen.  FYI, I'm the ghost of postban future.  Heed my warnings!

Comment: I want http://stackoverflow.com/awalgarg/ for me... possible?

Comment: @AwalGarg No, it is stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<custom>

Comment: @AwalGarg +1. It would be nice to get that, but I don't think it will be possible: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253537/why-are-usernames-not-unique-here-on-stack-overflow?rq=1

Comment: `/123456/myname` is still ugly. it needs to be `/myname`. In fact, I'd pay $5 to get a nice looking path string.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston then you might like https://stackoverflow.name/! Disclaimer: I'm the author. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update but that `.name` is a different org / url. The people want `stackoverflow.com/johnhancock` for example.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The trailing part of your Stack Overflow URL comes from what your display name is set to. Since you're a new user, your display name is auto-generated - if you look up next to your question you'll see that yours is user3305206. You can edit your display name by going to your profile on the main Stack Overflow site, and then clicking the "edit" button. From there you will be able to set it to something custom rather than the auto-generated name you have now.

Comment: Remember you can use whatever you want as the part after the user id no matter what your username is. e.g. http://stackexchange.com/users/4012123/worldsbestprogrammer

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett Of course, one should always [use this power responsibly](http://stackexchange.com/users/4012123/worldsworstprogrammer)

Answer (score -5):

I also wanted a vanity URL for Stack Overflow, so I created [stackoverflow.name](https://stackoverflow.name/). Just drop your Stack Overflow account URL into the tool (mine is "https://stackoverflow.com/users/2103602/sigpwned"), and it'll generate a vanity URL for your account automatically using your username (mine is "https://stackoverflow.name/sigpwned").

It's a simple little thing, and will never track you or anything like that. You don't even need to create an account or log in with SO. All you have to do is paste your Stack Overflow account URL, and it'll handle the rest.

I hope everyone finds it useful!

Comment: Nice but what if 2 Users (`/users/111111/tom` and `/users/222222/tom`) both want to use your Site...? => Will one get `https://stackoverflow.name/tom` and the next one `https://stackoverflow.name/tom1`...? But then 3rd User (`/users/333333/tom1`) will also want their "vanity URL", but will get `https://stackoverflow.name/tom11` instead...?