# How do I really get a custom Stack Overflow URL?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Different to [How do I get a custom Stack Overflow URL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275444/674039).  Would stack exchange devs consider to offer users a utility to generate a prettier one, *without the numeric user id* in the url?  It will look better for users who want to include it on CV, business card, etc.

They can be generated on demand (first-come-first-served basis).  Linkedin has this, and Facebook offered a similar utility some years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange already offers this on Careers 2.0. I have http://careers.stackoverflow.com/zopatista, for example, and companies have similar urls under `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company`. This is logical, the site focuses on CVs for great engineers, and matching them to job listings.

Stack Overflow, on the other hand, is a site that focuses on great questions with even better answers. The content is king here, not the users that produced it (pesky detail that). As such, vanity URLs are not really something the site should focus on.

Even better, Careers lets me select a few top postings, *and* link forward to my Stack Overflow account. I'd consider putting the Careers link on a business card, more so than my Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: Yeah I'm with Martijn on this and have spare invites for Careers 2.0 if you need one? It also has a pretty cool CV generator once you have filled in all your details, and space to include all your projects that you have worked on.

Comment: I can't find where to do it on careers.  My link is just like  http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/users/info/118147

Comment: @wim http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199671/give-career-users-a-clear-and-shareable-url-to-show-their-profiles