# Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed temporarily to the "#LoveOverflows" logo?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, logo

Stack Exchange [just tweeted](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/614467270753042432) this image following the Supreme Court of the United States ruling in favor of gay marriage:

[image]

[#LoveWins](https://twitter.com/hashtag/LoveWins?src=hash)
[#LoveOverflows](https://twitter.com/hashtag/LoveOverflows?src=hash)

Please can this be made the logo for a couple of days? I'm thinking Stack Overflow.

---

[LoveOverflow chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81674/loveoverflow) for the more... off topic discussions on a loosely on topic post.

Comment: Some issues are transcendent and deserve special notice.

Comment: Because you show that you care for people's right ?

Comment: I'm all for it, relevance-be-damned.

Comment: [I think you guys missed the joke.](http://sfist.com/2014/05/19/silicon_valley_recap_youre_gay_for.php)

Comment: The SO community is international, so I'm not sure why it should be affected by a decision of an USA court. Maybe it would be more appropriate to do this the International Gay Pride Day?

Comment: @Oriol -  When is International Gay Pride Day? I know that June is Pride Month and this weekend is the anniversary of the Stonewall Riot. (Yeah, the ruling happening today was not a coincidence.)

Comment: @Oriol SE is an American company.

Comment: @BSMP No idea. I searched it in my Wikipedia and it says it's around 28th June (in two days, what a coincidence!), or the first Saturday after that date. But the English Wikipedia seems to say it's a Pride Month, not a Pride Day. So maybe it isn't that international.

Comment: Anyone voting to close this as "This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow" - umm, we're talking about changing the logo. Wait, does Stack Overflow have a logo?

Comment: @Tim I actually had to check the header to see what the logo was...

Comment: I approve this message!!!  I'd love to see it, and I'm a happily married straight guy!

Comment: @Oriol - I think perhaps that particular date is celebrated internationally but the US happens to have celebrations for the whole month. I could be wrong though.

Comment: ... rainboverflow?

Comment: Anyone notice that Indigo or Violet is missing?

Comment: @Tim - I think Matt was referring to the V in ROYGBIV

Comment: A monumental day indeed, celebrating tolerance.  Too bad my highly voted comment was edited by somebody, an SE employee presumably, totally changing its meaning.  Not so tolerant.

Comment: @Tim Silly ignorant me.... Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @HansPassant - So it was your comment Sotirios Delimanolis was referring to in "missed the joke"?

Comment: No, he linked elsewhere.

Comment: I would also like to know what happened to @HansPassant's original comment? I'm all in favor of changing the logo, but removing comments that calmly debate the question seems heavy-handed.

Comment: @BSMP I commented "Are you gay for my code?" which is a line out of the HBO show Silicon Valley. I thought it was funny (in the proper context). I guess not.

Comment: I also don't see infrared or ultraviolet. But I approve!

Comment: @kevin Are you also going to change the meta icon or are you just changing the main site?

Comment: @NathanOliver just the main site

Comment: I see the new icon on my screen already: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=7bf4c6c915c2 (instead of [the old one](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1bc768be1b3c))

Comment: I see the change has been made. Cool beans

Comment: *"Marry whomever you love. Even if they're not a developer".*

Comment: @BSMP see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253537/why-are-usernames-not-unique-here-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Turns out I can't flag the new logo as [#OffTopic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/help-us-make-off-topic-close-reasons-clearer-to-the-op/169824#169824)

Comment: If we allow gay marriage, what will come next? Developers getting married?

Comment: @ssube - developers marrying other developers. ~~shudder~~

Comment: @Oded developers bringing their children up as developers... where will it end...?

Comment: @Oded so long as they write up the requirements before the wedding, that could be a happy and efficient union.

Comment: @Tim - it's developers all the way down! (or is it up? not sure)

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - Tim Post already asked this but how is the logo of the site off topic?

Comment: Just as long as the developers don't marry testers we are okay.

Comment: I for one am against c++ developers having relationships with java developers :)

Comment: Why logo not change for meta?

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName It has... its the b&w version

Comment: @ssube - You kid but having a project plan with requirements is actually a really good way to plan a wedding.

Comment: @BSMP What would the acceptance criteria look like for that? "1. Be legally wed. 2. Remain legally wed."

Comment: To have and to hold, in stack overflows and health.

Comment: @KevinMontrose How long will this be for? The weekend or the month?

Comment: @ssube - Um, yes, like that. What we actually had was: "A. B and C are married. B. Family and friends should enjoy our union." This is getting off topic but I recommend it. It helps to write out which things are important and in what order.

Comment: @Tim the weekend is the plan.

Comment: TIL more users than I thought on Stack Exchange are non-straight, non-cisgender. (I am too.)

Comment: Even as a straight, non-American male, I'm loving this.

Comment: You don't have to be gay to support gay rights.  It's a matter of equal representation and treatment that everyone should have.

Comment: @Matt a.k.a. indigo/violet Matt: Adding those (or "sky blue" for that matter) would make it the [flag of Cusco, "wrongly associated with the Inca empire"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag), and just imagine what kind of debate that would fuel ;). Other than that: Glad you went for it, SO!

Comment: Github changed theirs too https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/icons/pridetocat.png

Comment: I'm in full support of this. The logo should not be viewed as Stack Overflow taking a position on a social issue, but as a celebration of an important moment for a lot of members of our community.

Comment: Programming should stay out of politics.

Comment: @cpburnz regarding your close vote: this isn't stack overflow. This is meta stack overflow.

Comment: What has StackOverflow got to do with Gay rights? Just curious

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu a large number of the employees (including the owner) are gay. They are an american company. And this isn't gay right btw, this is equal rights.

Comment: Tomato,tomayto...I don't really care about the sexual orientation of the owners,SO should stay COMPLETELY out of politics.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu I've said this before, it's not politics, it's about people.

Comment: I think StackOverflow should keep the rainbowlicious logo in honor of my not-quite-five-year-old niece, whose favorite color is "rainbow". :)

Comment: Yes,but the issue is a political one.

Comment: If developers start marrying developers, God forbid, I am confused on what exactly a pull request will refer to...

Comment: Yes, please and thank you.

Comment: It's Pride weekend in London as well. The timing is perfect ;)

Comment: @marko yes, and I think in america (i'm not american) it is pride month. I think the SCOTUS chose this day on purpose :-)

Comment: As freedom expands, everyone benefits. No stack is left behind. Let's celebrate.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu - no the issue is not political. Politicians have hijacked it, but the issue itself is entirely a people issue.

Comment: Call it what you will, but the rainbow icon does **NOT** encompass love ... it does not stand for *love overflows* ...it is an icon specific to one agenda. It is an agenda to which I am vehemently opposed and I believe that those who oppose it (the majority) are being marginalized in favor of a very small minority.

Comment: @IAbstract What does it encompass? I see it as equality for everyone, and right now, that means changing the laws in favour of LGTBQ+ people.

Comment: a sampling of one is **not** *(the majority)* anyone on SO should know enough about statistics to know that and understand confirmation bias and all the other logical fallacies that *(the majority)* in this context represent.

Comment: @IAbstract, the majority do not oppose this agenda. Gay marriage has about 60% acceptance in the U.S. However, I think the issue at hand here is whether this should be broadcast to all SO users.

Comment: Tim, your edit that it's "nice to see the positive, pro equal answers have been voted up to the top" is exactly the problem: anyone who disagrees that this court decision is a positive, and even _anyone who disagrees that a court decision should be advertised on SO_, has now been labeled as negative and anti-equality. That's not what I want to see on SO.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, because people have been negative about it. People saying we can't celebrate a victory is negative.

Comment: in the US your rights end where others begin, and telling a group they can not do something that has absolutely no positive or negative effect on you is where your *rights* end. especially when it is a *personal belief* system predicated on the opposite of science, logic and reason.

Comment: Tim, no one is saying you can't celebrate a victory - heck, I'm celebrating it myself. We'd just rather the celebration happen outside of this particular venue.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Why? Why can't everyone celebrate? Including the people behind the scenes who this affects? Why can't they let their feelings out. If you have a blog, post yours there. Well SE have a worldwide site, and they're doing the same.

Comment: @ssube: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake

Comment: For the second time, no is saying that not everyone can celebrate. Do you see the distinction between "you shouldn't be allowed to feel feelings" and "no shouting in the library"? But if you think of SO as nothing more than a glorified blog, I guess there isn't much point in arguing for neutrality.

Comment: @IAbstract: I guess it depends on how you measure support. I'd be very sad if it turns out more North Americans are opposed to the SC decision than in favour - I'd be surprised too. Did you see the Ireland referendum? 2:1 in favour of marriage equality, and that's from a (previously?) sectarian, very Catholic country.

Comment: I find the statement *"Marry whomever you love. Even if they're not a developer"* offensive - **How could someone marry a non-developer?**

Comment: The people who honestly don't have anything against gay people and are truthfully only against this because stackoverflow is never supposed to do anything other than answer programming questions probably really hated hats.

Comment: Well done America - from an English poof.

Comment: @Martha - I have a pot of Tartan paint in the garage if your niece is interested?!

Comment: Finally... Something that tops the Pastafarianism proposal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could you watch the close / open status of this question. I fear it may be about to be closed again...

Comment: @tim: I'm sorta inclined to lock it for a few days.  It's already attracted far too much attention.

Comment: Btw, if anyone wants to copy and use [my rainbow avatar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472495/halfer?tab=profile) for the purposes of celebration, please go ahead `:-)`.

Answer (score 1573, accepted):

I am in favor of this.

We wouldn't be doing it to promote social causes, nor would we be doing it to hitch our brand-wagon onto a popular cause. We're just doing it to celebrate how fast the world is moving towards acceptance of gay people.

I'm the CEO, co-founder, and inventor of Stack Overflow. I'm gay, American, and married, and have taken a lot of crap over the years for all three of those things, so this is a big day for me.

When I was a kid, gay marriage was impossible to imagine. I remember reading a bestselling book about sex when I was a teenager that was in favor of all kinds of sexual practices but drew the line at gay marriage, which it presented as the most ridiculous kind of clownishness possible. A whole chapter on homosexuals was morbidly obsessed with how they were always showing up in the hospital with hilarious inappropriate things stuck in inappropriate places. After I read that I thought I would have to keep my preferences secret forever.

Thankfully, braver people than I realized that if enough people know somebody who is gay, they will understand that being gay is not some kind of freak-show threat to society -- it's perfectly normal and entirely harmless. So as more and more people came out of the closet, society became slowly more and more accepting of homosexuality.

I've been in a long committed relationship with the same man for a couple of decades now, and there have been many times where the next thing that relationship really needed was a formal, state-recognized commitment ceremony, but until recently, that was not a legal option.

One night I tuned into a cable tv channel and watched the incompetent, criminally corrupt, venal New York state legislature somehow manage to eke out a law allowing gay marriage and suddenly I was a real citizen for the first time. Despite my normal calm nature I couldn't help but cry tears of joy.

Today's Supreme Court decision is monumental. It reflects a distinct change in American society, from being nearly universally against allowing gay people to marry, to having a solid majority in favor. It's a great moment.

Very few people here would dispute this. Almost everyone arguing against changing the Stack Overflow logo to the rainbow logo for a day or two are just saying "this is not the place" or that somehow Stack Overflow should be seen as neutral on social issues, not taking a stand on what could be a controversial issue.

That's missing the point.

The point is that allowing EVERYONE to marry IS the neutral position.

On Stack Overflow we don't care if you're black, white, brown, or purple, as long as you know the answer to a programming question, you'll get the upvote. We don't care if you're straight, gay, bi, trans, queer, asexual, intersexual, questioning, poly, or a sandwich, we only care if you're right. That's a fundamental, core value of Stack Overflow. Whoever you are, you are equal in our eyes.

That's what the Supreme Court just ruled.

Couldn't be more relevant to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is the real answer. I was waiting for you, Joel. <3

Comment: Hopefully Anna is in the office today. Something tells me she'd be thrilled and honored.

Comment: "I'm the CEO, co-founder, and inventor of Stack Overflow, I'm gay, American, and married, and have taken a lot of crap over the years for all three of those things..." - which three have you taken crap for? :P

Comment: @Qix I'm pretty excited today, along with many others. :)

Comment: a) you yourself said "I wouldn't want" "all kinds of awareness ribbons of various colors"... guess you've changed your mind on that b) clearly this particular topic is not neutral, as it was very recently tightly contested in a high court c) any individual's position on any individual issue is not relevant to the topic of whether the site should be used to celebrate social causes d) it's right and proper that stackoverflow is agnostic to sexual orientation. it should celebrate agnosticism on nonprogramming issues by NOT changing the logo

Comment: @AnnaLear <3 I hope the unicorn is out today, too.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and upvote on the assumption you meant "for all *four* of those things"

Comment: Allowing *all americans* to marry, is, sadly not allowing *everyone*. Gays are hugely discriminated in Italy my home country. I'm happy that you are happy, do celebrate! But today I'm a bit sad because I'm not proud of Italy.

Comment: Sandwiches still can't properly use the mouse or keyboard.  This is discrimination at its finest and it must be changed.

Comment: Grammar correction edit within 3 minutes. I love SO.

Comment: So tl;dr, we should change the logo because we want to celebrate more people becoming more equal.

Comment: But, despite of all these upvotes,  I can't  agree with this.

Comment: I gotta say, you've surely gotta care whether or not I'm a sandwich. You can't sell sandwiches advertisements or job interviews. What is your revenue model from having sandwiches view your website?

Comment: Damn it, who's cutting all these onions in my office?

Comment: @Sklivvz I feel similarly about Russia as you do about Italy. Hopefully as more and more countries legalize marriage for all, others will follow.

Comment: Not to promote **social** causes, but to celebrate the acceptance of a certain type of **people**? Okay, Joel.

Comment: In a Stack Overflow podcast, didn't Joel and Jeff once discuss the importance of knowing times to break the rules, e.g., in a time of celebration, or just in moments of fun?

Comment: If your argument against a logo change amounts to "Oh no, someone might think I'm gay and discriminate against me"... Welp. Welcome to my world. ;)

Comment: Let's not publicly shame @Vesper.  They gave an opinion that's personal, as are all of ours.  The thing I love best about SE is the convergence of different perspectives.  (Personally, though, I vote to change the logo to mark the historic occasion!)

Comment: I do wonder why social causes need publicity on Q/A sites that are not about social causes?

Comment: Joel, is this cause directly threatening SO? Or could this  be considered a 'slippery slope'? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114026/137116

Comment: Who cares @Chase? I'm not American, so this doesn't have any impact on my life at all currently. It does have an impact on millions of others lives though - including the owner of this website. Why not be happy for them? All of them. For the avoidance of doubt I'm also gay.

Comment: @AnnaLear verbal +1; comment votes are maxed out, sadly.

Comment: Thanks for this @Joel :) It takes people who aren't afraid of judgement to make equality a real thing and it's decisions like this that made this day a reality.

Comment: Regardless of whether you disagree, one does not simply downvote Joel Spolsky. :P

Comment: @nicael Oh well, never mind.

Comment: @Joel can you edit the "status-completed"ness into your answer?

Comment: Wow, what a read. Couldn't agree more.

Comment: +1 for the new logo, for all sorts of reasons, but also just because it is nicer. The bland orange one is just so... meh. I like a bit of colour. The world is **colourful**... also, I come from the rainbow nation.

Comment: Also, be proud of *just how well* stack exchange works.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: It's your company and site, but in 2011, [you said that "there is a difference between promoting "all kinds of awareness ribbons of various colors" (which I wouldn't want) and opposing a law that threatens the very site itself."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114026/572). You mentioned the slippery slope - isn't this going down it? This is a social and political issue in the US and doesn't affect Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, or the majority of users and visitors come from outside the United States. Wouldn't the blog be more appropriate? If not, what has changed in the last 4 years or so?

Comment: Or even just promoting it on stackexchange, rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Let's make it permanent. I think it's a good looking logo w/ or w/out any other meaning.

Comment: To all the people [quoting Joel's previous, 4-year-old answer, you're missing the end](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes/114026#114026): "There are very, very few situations that are important enough to try to get your attention. I hope that we continue to make the right call as to what's really important and what's merely nice to have, but it's always a judgement call." A "judgement call". By the people who own and run this site, to whom it is obviously "really important"... Embrace diversity.

Comment: @Luggage we should add an unicorn and pancakes though. Then it would perfectly fit SO.

Comment: Where did my comment and Pekka's response to it go?

Comment: I knew I liked SO for a reason.

Comment: Allowing everyone to marry is a you are an heteronomous decision in favor of the homosexual. You are demanding that you be right, instead of the opposition, which says they are. I'd welcome you to view this talk by noted Christian apologist on the christian's view of homosexuality: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPYRXop7aPA

Comment: This doesn't allow everyone to marry. It opens it up to gay marriage but still discriminates against other groups.

Comment: @LyeFish I'm sorry, what other groups can't yet marry? (that's a legit question, I can't think of any other groups in America being legally prohibited from marrying. _Of course_ this is not the same in other countries, so that may be what I am missing from the context of your comment.)

Comment: @Kendra: Yes, it's a legit question. Polygamists, for starters. As long as we have a social institution defined government, there will (naturally) be parameters defining inclusion, which means there will always be exclusion. I posted a comment earlier giving a libertarian perspective, but it seems as though it was almost immediately deleted.

Comment: @LyeFish Thank you for clarifying. (That group certainly hadn't come to mind.) As for the deletion, it might have been that several people flagged it and it was auto-deleted. I wouldn't be surprised if that was happening to several comments here. Though given a few missing (obsolete) comments of my own, it could just be mods pruning comments to try to keep things in hand.

Comment: @Kendra: I agree  though the comment was very neutral with respect to marriage but brought up the fact that there are deeper governmental issues at stake with respect to autonomy of the states. Doesn't really speak to tolerance and acceptance of diversity of thought that people would flag it.

Comment: I'd prefer a world where people don't need to come out at all and there would be no need for logos like this either. But we don't live in that world yet, even though we're a step closer to it today than yesterday.

Comment: @biziclop: It could be argued that we're a step further from it. To get truly closer to it, there should be no government involvement. Government should treat people equally and offer the same benefits/programs irrespective of marital status. That's how I see it anyway.

Comment: @LyeFish I respectfully disagree, I don't think government has anything to do with it. Every human society (irrespective of government) has institutions, and marriage is just one of them. It will take a long time until being gay would be seen as something similar to being left-handed (which was also something to be ashamed of for my parents' generation), but it will require a change in social attitudes, not government.

Comment: I don't know why this was ever an issue, as long as you are of age and different blood line we shouldn't be restricted. There are so many dumb laws that exist today.

Comment: @biziclop: But we really need to guard against utilizing government to change people's opinions on social issues. That should happen naturally through effective use of our freedom of speech. Once we get government involved, we're creating all sorts of divisions like the ones we have today. In the past, government force has been used in terrible ways to uphold certain social opinions. I prefer not to give people that sort of power.

Comment: @LyeFish I don't see this as the right venue for political discourse, but will dive in anyways. The government chose to get into the regulating-couples game (imposing special rights in death, taxes and retirement, for example) and has done so in a discriminatory fashion. Of course, you could say that by regulating couples only, they have excluded trios, etc., but within the scope of regulating unions among two people, the last bit of discrimination has been removed. Thus: celebration, even from libertarians. Sure, I'd rather see government staying out of it, but that's not going to happen.

Comment: I'm in favour too. 
I once fell in love with a girl... Who then revealed being born as a male.
It was too late, I already was in love with HER. My vision of transgenders changed forever.

Comment: @LyeFish Oh, I see what you mean now. As an Eastern European I'm all too aware of the dangers of a government-imposed social order. But I believe in this case the decision merely acknowledges the already massive shift in social attitudes and draws a line in the sand. The Supreme Court haven't made the changes, just issued a `commit()` on the transaction.

Comment: @biziclop: The SC changes that concern me are those that impede on the autonomy of the states. Yes, there is a massive shift in attitudes but it's such a visible shift *because* of government having been involved. I really think that most people wouldn't give it a second thought if it hadn't been a political issue.

Comment: @Frank: I guess my reason for arguing these points here is that the SC decision can be seen as a negative without it being a stance of bigotry against gay people. I don't like the logo change, not because gays can now marry but because states can no longer choose for themselves. I prefer organic change to those that are forced. And I'd not take it for granted that government must be involved... but then I'm a dreamer. ;-)

Comment: @LyeFish Yeah, depending on the court's reasoning, it could be a blow against states' rights. If it's narrowly restricted to this issue, though, I'm totally fine with forcing states to a uniform, nondiscriminatory policy...and with celebrating the unambiguously positive result that this policy is now in effect (even if it might have come at the expense of the constitution... I'm no lawyer and so won't judge that question) by putting up the logo. Anyway, I agree that there's no need to throw around accusations of bigotry just on the basis of disagreeing with the logo change.

Comment: @Frank: I hear you. I'd just say that it's easy to be nonchalant about states rights when it's something one agrees with. But give the Federal government such power to rule the states and then get some people in authority who wish to impose tyrannical law and one's opinion may change.

Comment: To me, this post is nothing but spin and rationalization. Next it'll be some environmental thing and the logo will be a tree for a few days because nature is beautiful and beautiful code generally runs better and that's what we're all about. I get that many people are happy about this court decision (myself included), but the excuses aren't fooling me. SO is endorsing a political decision because the site owner likes it, plain and simple.

Comment: @terdon And I think that's bad. It makes him sound like a politician.

Comment: You know what ? Actually this new logo is real beautiful per se (apart from what it means which is +1) :)

Comment: This is just a propaganda move from the owner of this site to use its popularity to propagate his own controversial opinion. This act and making the SO community to look like a LGBT activist and political lobbyst disgusts me and is highly against to the fundaments of this community.

Comment: Very well said Joel!

Comment: In my country , population exceeds 1.3 billions( compared to what? 320 millions?) and a small decision made by supreme court is likely to impact far more people than other countries have ever seen. Would you be changing logo for each such event (so that I can roll out a few logos every month for you) or was this an exception. While I do support this decision by supreme court of Your Country , but please keep in mind Your Country != Whole world.

Comment: Given that a bug of epic proportions has been fixed and the whole site is about "getting the logic right", this seems on topic on SO after all.

Comment: Great news for gays. But while we're at it... Maybe add a note on top that says TPP is going to pass? Ah no... This week was very weird. All kinds of news, but nothing on TPP passing the Senate... I'm starting to believe this all was carefully planned. (Charleston, the flag, now this).

Please, TPP is stripping away your rights. Gay marriage, but in return we will lose a lot more. Now waiting for the "bigot!" replies.

Comment: Love is the only thing that is transforming developers mind to a waste mind. But for supporting something social. Its a good approach.

Comment: We wouldn't be doing it to promote social causes, nor would we be doing it to hitch our brand-wagon onto a popular cause!!! BUT There "WILL" BE DONE!

Comment: @totymedli - "is highly against to the fundaments of this community": Perhaps you should take a look at the votes here and on all the other answers. I think it's pretty clear how the community feels about this. If having a rainbow-colored logo on a website "disgusts" you, well, you're going to have a difficult time this weekend.

Comment: @BradLarson & others – just a notice that even if people are celebrating, this doesn't neccesarily mean they are right or that this new gay *religion* is right. I am one of many people who believe that LGBTI was never how the Highest One created man and woman and He will judge these things which people celebrate today as a *sin* at the End of days. This is just a reminder that maybe the truth is elsewhere and people might not be necessarily right even if there was 100K upvotes. Personally, I'd vote -1 if it was possible.

Comment: Freedom of speech is that your comments would be deleted if it is against the belief of the CEO of a site.  Well, its your site, your rules.

Comment: Marry whomever you love.  Even if they're not a developer.

Comment: I have benefited enormously from my involvement with SE, and am hugely grateful for the effort you and the team have put into it. I didn't know you are gay, and I don't feel any different about you now that I do, I'm still grateful and your work helps my work every day. However my conscience is telling me I need to reconsider my own involvement. Judging by the votes on the answers here, what you have chosen to do has broad support, but is nevertheless divisive. With hindsight, do you still think this was the correct thing to do?

Comment: @BradLarson I don't think the community feeling about this change is so clear. Posts are getting *lots* of ups and *lots* of downs, and while the former seem to be more at a first glance, the disagreement is still strong. Might be 20% (so the flag proposal would have "passed" in a democratic vote), but still 20% translates into thousands of people in the network. I guess no feature-request with hundreds of downvotes has ever been accepted. A few hours of discussion seem not enough to me for a community-driven website.

Comment: @Jack `With hindsight, do you still think this was the correct thing to do?` lol, anyone with a little bit of familiarity with Meta knew, with 100% certainty, that loads of argument and drama were going to be completely unavoidable. No hindsight necessary. :)

Comment: Kind of sad that this beautiful, moving answer will remain buried on Meta in the long term. It should really have a more prominent spot somewhere (but can't think of a good one)

Comment: @miroxlav leaving aside my personal opinions about the position you seem to espouse, calling homosexuality "new" is [both absurd and completely without historical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_homosexuality). In fact, what is new is the puritanical position against it in many modern societies. Open a book before posting next time, or even spend two seconds on wikipedia and you might avoid making yourself sound quite so embarrassingly ignorant. You have every right to your own opinions, but don't attempt to pass those off as historical fact.

Comment: @BradLarson These upvotes are not a representative survey about the opinion of the community. Even if it would be, according to the votes/comments the closest conclusion you can make is that this case is controversial and divisive. It is against of the community fundamentals because for a political view (that is totally unrelated to this sites purpose) they stir up the community. I respect Joel as a founder, but what made this site succesfull and what is really behind it is the community and this act is a backstabbing, sacrificing the community in favor of a political opinion.

Comment: What other metric can we use to make a representative survey of the opinion of the community then?

Comment: Great news for gays indeed. Besides, now we've learned that once we attempt to talk nasty about gay marriages and/or make jokes (those of which only *we* think they're funny mostly) we'll __insult the co-founder__ and inventor of this great site *in person*! A person who created a site which helped us countless times in the past. Way to think about it twice (or thrice even) I reckon.

Comment: It's not about the logo change. I don't care even if the logo is set it to rainbow permanently. My concern is why we show support in favor of a decision. Would SO support some other decision that affects even greater number of people in the world? The questions asked in the posts by "Rolf" and "TigerhawkT3" need to be answered. 
But the mods and others conveniently ignore that and divert with simplistic questions "what's wrong with logo change for a day?", 
"why are you people against celebrating it?" etc. FTR, I am an atheist and I think it's a good decision. But it just doesn't belong here.

Comment: I'm proud to live in a country that was among the first (in modern times) to accept gay marriage. And I think this decision shows that America is becoming more tolerant, hopefully not just for gay people but towards anyone. Still, I was surprised by the logo-change. I think it's cute, but since Stack Overflow's logo didn't change on other historic events (wars ending, stuff like that), it seems to mainly reflect the personal stance of the founders on this particular topic. So, to keep it fair and end the discussion, Stack Overflow should go completely Google Doodle on its logo from now on. :)

Comment: Are we going to change logo to pink on AIDS day -No, pink is for breast cancer awareness. The ribbon color for HIV/AIDS is red.

Comment: I really don't get this demand for absolute consistency, as if this celebratory gesture meant SO would have to support all worthy causes, or all "more worthy" causes, or that it dooms SO down a slippery slope of activism. Taken to the limit, that line of reasoning would mean no organisation would be able to take any public stance on any issue - there are too many bad things in the world, and no algorithm to decide which issues are more important, or to optimise the effort dedicated to them.

Comment: @totymedli: You might be confusing the community’s fundamentals with the community’s fundamentalists.

Comment: This is a great day for all purple sandwiches on SO.

Comment: Programming ability aside...I draw the line at purple, personally.

Comment: aw, i just get the gray logo when sharing this on facebook

Comment: Atlast you edited and added 'bi' in the sex categories, now I can rest in peace.

Comment: I think many people here are confusing support for equal marriage [in one country] with support for Stack Overflow's logo being replaced with a rainbow version. The two are _not_ the same.

Comment: Personally, I'm a little tired of Rainbow-washing (how many companies doing it are all that diverse?) but I favor this icon as personal congrats to Joel and and all the other LGBTQ folks on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Spin and rationalize it any way you want, it is completely off topic forStackOverflow. Go start GayExchange and change the logo all you want.

Comment: Stack Overflow is super strict, but one of the reason's I love it is because the community makes the decisions, which it is doing right here. The community makes and breaks the rules depending on its populace.

Comment: Bad decision. We're not supposed to care what someone else's color, sex, gender, persuasion, religion, nationality, age, etc is.  Which of the other prior SCOTUS rulings can we change the logo for next? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_United_States_Supreme_Court_cases

Comment: I agree for the idea of placing a rainbow logo for celebration, it's probably one of the few moments deserving it. IMO however it shouldn't have been done for the profile pages... the reason is that someone coming directly to a profile page from an external link (e.g. placed in a cv or in a blog) will probably infer a strong association of the user with the celebration that may be or may not be accurate. SO wants to celebrate... ok; but it should make clear that not every contributor is celebrating (some -sadly- aren't celebrating at all).

Comment: @terdon – you are right, good point. I should have used *modern* or *age-old* or both. So, please, re-read my post with this substitution.

Comment: Why not every year? Yes, the SCOTUS decision is a big deal to those of ye in the United States and its territories, and will have an impact beyond that country, but the events on this day 46 years ago had a bigger impact, including in leading to SCOTUS even considering this issue, which is why we commemorate it around the world. Pride/Christopher Street Liberation Day/Rainbow Parade/various other names in other places is unusual in its being an annual celebration that has long-since moved from its New York roots to be truly international.

Comment: Well the question is quite something, coz user found q tweet by SE and and wanted to make the site colorful, simple.. But what is this answer about? Your personal opinions? ** When I was a kid, gay marriage was impossible to imagine. I remember reading a bestselling book about sex... A whole chapter on homosexuals was morbidly obsessed.. inappropriate things stuck in inappropriate places.. I would have to keep my preferences secret forever.** what? Is it someones own story he is writing out of all sudden happiness(also backed up by our dear moderators and high rep users)..

Comment: This answer even shouldnt belong here.. And if its all ok about this answer tomorrow i would like to paste my biography on another question!! It would be worth right? And on a second thought, if this answer gets a lot of upvotes, i guess every other answer on so and mso which was deleted for any reason should be honoured with those many upvotes, from those who upvoted this answer just because its an answer from SE CEO.. God bless all moderators. :)

Comment: I think people need to relax. It hurts nothing to give the logo some color to in honor of social progress.

Comment: I am happy for the SC ruling. But you know what else is NEUTRAL  as you put it - abolition of all income tax and welfare state programs, abolition of all government regulation in private sector, hate speech against Islam. Would StackOverflow be ok with postings on these topics?

Comment: I really like the logo, but please have the standard one show up on users' pages, to keep that one completely free of politics - and yes, if this wasn't a political *and* politically controverse opinion, we wouldn't have needed a supreme court's ruling on it :)

Comment: The neutral position is 'Stack Overflow has no opinion concerning the nature of marriage' not 'Stack Overfow supports uninhibited marriage'; the attempt to invert the meaning of 'neutral' seems rather contrived.

Comment: It might be a big day for you Joel, Congrats! But we should be discussing topics relevant to programming instead diverting reader's mind. As I got mine diverted, I actually forget what I was looking for at stackoverlow :P

Comment: @minitech Oh, the typical LGBT response: If you don't support this, you are a sectarian, a fundamentalist, a bigot, an extremist, a hater, a homophobe. No. I just raise my voice against political propaganda. Do I even have the right to tell my opinion without being stigmatized?

Comment: @totymedli: No, you don’t have that right. You have the right to your opinion, but other people are not obligated to like you for it.

Comment: I think its interesting that people tend to forget that they're playing in someone else's sandbox with someone else's toys... If you don't like the rules in this sandbox, feel free to build your own. Congratulations @Joel [marriage is a wonderful institution...](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/g/grouchomar157484.html)

Comment: I want to marry my sister and my brother are you in favor of me doing that? or do not not really mean marry who you want?

Comment: @AdamLear `I feel similarly about Russia...` The democracy is the ruling of the majority as a result of polling. This means the minority must follow the majority after the ruling. This is the key of social democratic contract.
Only when a country is democratic, the country follows the majority instead of a very small hyperactive minority. What countries follow the ruling of the majority today?

Comment: @AdamLear `If your argument against a logo change...` Not so. The argument is "Why do they force me to accept for their ill fame by associating me with the distorted-rainbow-colored logo in spite of myself, without polling? I have not signed this in the user agreement of SO. Why do they force me celebrate this day without polling? This is not democratic".

Comment: @BradLarson `I think it's pretty clear how the community feels about this.` The hyperactivity of the minority does not mean the silence and acceptance of the majority: the majority have real tasks that to pay attention to forcing "celebration" with the deforcement-rainbow-like colored logo.

Comment: Before anybody else says that the logo takes a "neutral" stance by supporting equal rights, please scroll down to the Christian guy who posted and explain why his post has been downvoted into oblivion, thank you. Personally I used to think that this was a professional and politically neutral website but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: Actually the "neutral" position is a deregulation of marriage. Single people (and polyamorous people) continue to be discriminated against under the law, compared to "couples", who get special rights and options.

Comment: @minitech And thats why the logo change should have never happened.

Comment: @Kobi - yes, they can't. Most marriage laws in the past are to protect children, at least implicitly. In Catholic church, (potential) fertility and a will to have children is explicitly required.

Comment: I think that the logo should stay. I'm not gay nor American, yet I feel happy for you guys, you are neutral now. You are a part of the American Marriage System. This was a step to neutrality and non-discrimination. Next step: Worldwide Legalization of Homosexual Marriage. Then, minority rights. Then more... If you didn't like this news, you are nothing but a Terrorist in my eye, even if you didn't like it, see it as a step to equalization... (oh boy, Tim Cooks, Joel Spolsky, who is next to turn up, Bill Gates?)

Comment: @Flimm: That’s… not true at all. You literally only have to look at the second highest answer.

Comment: @minitech: The [second highest answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297865/247696) expresses disagreement with the logo, but it does not express disagreement with the supreme court's decision, which is relevant and on-topic. I phrased it badly, I should have said: "expressed disagreement with both the logo and the supreme court".

Comment: Don't have hard-feelings against me. I'm against gay stuff in general, but if it makes you happy you have my congratulations on your victory. If I care about it, I don't. You do what you want. But, please, don't overflow it to other countries that have nothing to do with it. But now it is too late for such request. I respect your decision to open up and support it, even though I'm against it. I just with the most sincere happiness you can have.

Comment: @Flimm: That’s also not true; just take a look at the lowest-voted answer, for instance. Of course, this not being Meta Supreme Court of the United States, there’s going to be less of that than talk about the logo.

Comment: @minitech: I guess a confusing sentence in the side-note of that answer could be interpreted as disagreeing with the court's decision. I take it back and delete my comment. There's one deleted answer and one deleted question I would undelete, but I support the mods in general, and I guess I'll leave this alone for now and wait a few days for SO to become non-political again. If you think it's important feel free to contact me.

Comment: This is a disaster. I am shocked. People misusing SO for their own political concerns and beliefs. The whole discussion belongs to politics stack-exchange. Also, there is nothing like neutrality; every "neutral" statement is a value judgement.

Comment: But do you need to advertise it all around? I am married with woman, is there a need to advertise this everywhere? Make special logos, parades, etc?

Comment: @Joel Spolsky "The point is that allowing EVERYONE to marry IS the neutral position."  -- Politically I agree with you, but no it isn't. It most definitely is not a neutral position. If it were, this wouldn't be a debate or even a question. Your bias is in the way. I sincerely hope SO doesn't turn into some stupid SJW outlet. Give them an inch and they'll take a lightyear. And yes, a small logo is an inch.

Special thanks to the conservative majority justices who allowed this to happen.

Comment: I was born in Russia and I think they do it correctly there on this issue. However, I respect the idea that Programming shouldn't relate to these issues in either case. I understand that this isn't my site, but without me and millions of other users, it wouldn't be anything. I can't demand anything, but it would make sense for Joel as an American to respect the opinion of others and understand that while he's purporting to defend some greater value, he's stepping on the hearts and values of many other people.

Comment: This stance on whether marriage should include people of the same sex is not only a subjective opinion, but it's being treated as an objective one.  I feel like by associating with this site I'm supporting a view that I don't agree with.  I should at least be able to officially opt out of seeing the new logo while I'm using the site.

Comment: Irrelevant to SO.  This judgment relates specifically to the USA. SO/SE is much, much bigger than that.

Comment: @IliaKoulikov - "I was born in Russia and I think they do it correctly there on this issue". Do you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_rights_in_Russia#Homophobia ?  Because this is not what I'd consider "respect the opinion of others". In my opinion, the current LGBT treatment in Russia deserves some "stepping on the hearts and values".

Comment: `The point is that allowing EVERYONE to marry IS the neutral position` - it's not, for the same reason that being in favor of legal polygamous marriages wouldn't be a "neutral position", or wanting to lower marriageable age down to 16 yo wouldn't be a "neutral position" (as of now it's 18 in the US I think, but eg. 14 in Columbia - "EVERYONE"?). Marriage by definition is a social construct and not an individual right. Maybe favoring gay marriages is the right thing, but it's still a stance - opting for extending the definition of this social construct - no matter how much you pretend it isn't

Comment: Of course we all love to think that our point of view IS the neutral position :) I'm aware of that, but it's a (convenient) delusion

Comment: Joel's hypocrisy is well illustrated by sentences like "The point is that allowing EVERYONE to marry IS the neutral position." But Joel hasn't, SO hasn't, and the SCOTUS hasn't taken that position. They've only celebrated the right for one particular group to marry. Marrying one's mother, brother, 2-year-old neighbor, neighbor's wife, dog, or robot are still not sanctioned. So be honest about what you're really celebrating, and stop pretending to be taking a neutral position.

Comment: I don't see how sexual orientation has anything to do with Stack Overflow, unless your genitals are reasoning out solutions to programming problems and typing code. The neutral position is to actually to not talk about things that are not related to code.

Comment: I think the point Joel is making is that this is not really an issue where each side has its pros and cons, and roughly equal weight. Rather this is an issue where a minority was being oppressed and now isn't. That this is supposedly controversial is only a result of discriminatory propaganda distorting the picture. The world is now more free than it was before. The logo is a celebration of freedom in general.

Comment: @LarsH There may or may not be justified limits to marriage, but gender is not one of them.

Comment: The minority were not oppressed, @Sahuagin. Are they forced to go to different schools? Are they prevented from voting? If they wanted social benefits and inheritance rights, fine! By all means. Why do they insist it be called a marriage? Is it to mock normals? Now, normals are the majority, and yet they're oppressed by this new definition of marriage. How about that? An oppressed majority, in a democracy?

Comment: And the normal logo is back, at last. The show may be over, but we do not forget.

Comment: " we only care if you're right. And agree with same sex marriage. That's a fundamental, core value of Stack Overflow." <-- corrected

Comment: As the logo has reverted, and I'm tired of cleaning up the fights that people are getting into within the comments, I'm locking this answer. If you wish to still have a discussion about this, take it to chat. Just please be civil and respectful to each other if you do so.

Answer (score 536):

Absolutely disagree, for the same reason I outlined in this old meta question:

[Please do not use Stack Overflow to promote social causes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes)

> Some issues are transcendent and deserve special notice.

Sing your hearts song wherever you want, but please not on the site where posting a Q or an A about it would be grounds for lock/close/deletion.

Comment: I think people need to relax. It hurts nothing to give the logo some color to in honor of social progress.

Comment: @BobHorn all social issues are "progressive" to some subset of the global population and "regressive" to another subset of the global population. It's not right or proper that stackoverflow be the voice for just one of those people. It should be neutral.

Comment: @BobHorn i'm sure there's a limitless supply of social issues you can take a principled stand on and you're welcome to do so... but NOT on StackOverflow, and certainty not via SO's logo

Comment: Stack Exchange bills itself as communities. This issue affects a big swath of the community. Including me. Your arguments about the SOPA announcment ignore the basic principal of SE/SO: The communities decide.

Comment: Isn't it like 10% of the population? That's not close to a majority

Comment: @DanielEvans United States court decisions *don't* affect more people than they *do* affect, if you want to use that argument. Regardless, SO is a worldwide community... "for professional and enthusiast programmers". Not "for professional and enthusiast United States court discussers"

Comment: @FactorMystic What does it hurt to do this?

Comment: @BobHorn please see my linked answer on the SOPA discussion for why this is a bad *principle for site operation*

Comment: _It should be neutral._ - Given the tweet, it's a little late for that.

Comment: @FactorMystic So you're pointing me to a question that has -4 overall downvotes? And that question still doesn't explain what it hurts. Do you really think SO will be any different tomorrow for changing the logo for a bit?

Comment: @BobHorn I linked it rather than simply copy/paste what I said before & additional discussion. The up/down vote count is in the 90's both way, so it was vigorously discussed. The situations are equivalent so the old argument still applies.

Comment: @FactorMystic If the community at large doesn't care, then they don't care. You are arguing that the communities should not be allowed to decide what they do and don't care about, for all intents and purposes because YOU don't care about it.

Comment: @TankorSmash: around 4%, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_demographics_of_the_United_States

Comment: @FactorMystic I think, the Rainbow Flag is rainbow to encompass *all* people...? Not just LGBT but LGBTS+?

Comment: Here as before, your comments are couched in language about how you think this is hurting the site, but it is patently obvious that you simply disagree with the politics being endorsed and it is annoying you personally. If you're so concerned about the community and the platform, then why do you seem unfazed by a huge amount of disagreement from the community?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist if you believe that I don't want to use SO to promote social causes because I don't believe in the social cause at hand, that is incorrect. My disagreement is purely on the principle of how the site should be run.

Comment: "**I am completely uninterested** in being badgered about social causes... **I am disgusted** by the recent Internet trend... **I hate** that Stack Overflow is doing this now too." Sorry I missed your communitarian language the first time and misinterpreted this as a personal annoyance of yours. My question stands: if you are so concerned about the community, why do you seem mostly unfazed by resistance from that same community to not doing things your way?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist those words are in reference to the topic, which is that SO is being used to promote social causes. Those words are not in reference to any particular social cause, nor are they an opinion on SOPA or marriage equality

Comment: Let's assume there are no gay employees in SE(including the CEO), would they still do what they do now? I doubt. That wouldn't make the gay rights any less of an issue, would it? Then why care of *some* social issues and not others? This has nothing to with whether I agree/disagree with the decision or I care about any social issues; it's simply whether we should be using SO for social causes(to discuss, support, oppose or otherwise).

Comment: @answer: I wholeheartedly agree!

Comment: What contentious social issue next?  Shall we change the logo to indicate StackOverflow's views of abortion, or guns, or Pacific trade, or whom the next U.S. President should be?

Comment: This isn't a social "cause". This is the righting of a wrong that was caused by the interlinking of Church and State for some reason.

Comment: I'm sad because I don't have enough reputation to vote you down

Comment: @BobHorn: there is no honor in this decision by the Supreme Court - moral concerns aside, the SCOTUS *did not* have the authority to expand the definition of marriage. They overstepped their constitutional authority.

Comment: I think you are confusing your belief that they expanded **your** narrow definition of marriage, I think you are just realizing your definition is not **the** definition of marriage, nor the *majority* one, if it was the comments and posts were be quite different than they are, I see only one person posting angry stuff about a logo change.

Comment: @IAbstract how much any individual agrees/disagrees with the United States court decisions should not impact whether it is appropriate for SO site operators to exploit the site to promote social causes

Comment: @FactorMystic: it is wholly inappropriate ... this is a political agenda and people are discussing it as such. The whole *separation of church and state* for instance (Gorb) ...that phrase has as much to do with the Constitution as the SCOTUS decision this morning.

Comment: got to agree with what you said, im straight and not american so this whole gay thing is none of my business and i believe in freedom and all, but if SO wants to decide promoting social causes, right now at this very moment, there are like 50 more important things, like today ISIS killed 150 civilian, perhaps some logo against that is better, so it should stay far away from all of this, cause if sometthing starts it will never ends. And perhaps some people are against same sex marriage and will be offended, so stay neutral

Comment: well have not seen this before in stackoverflow,a change of logo!.Where was the social cause and promotions for other issues?

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. Our university uses the same double standards and it's pure hypocrisy.

Comment: What is the line between what is relevant and what is not relevant? Why would SO choose one flag over another? Each part of the community might be more sensitive to one or the other cause. I do not want to diminish the importance of the event, but I feel like SO should stay within its purpose.

Comment: Totally agree about such irrelevant bs, keep SO logo straight!

Comment: While I respect the judgment on Same Sex marriages, I really wish if SO and its sister sites (those that don't specifically focus on issues like this) keep the focus off. It's a Q&A site for specific areas and focusing on issues like this doesn't make sense. There are more pressing issues than this like Climate engineering, pollution, Ozone layer issues, over population, corruption, greed, wars, genocides, animal death rates, Political issues, etc., So, let's not devote our time on such issues in StackExchange sites. There are definitely a whole lot of other places on Internet for such things.

Comment: @PietroSaccardi  Choose one flag over another? It would be fair to perhaps have a flag celebrating the unfair discrimination of gays tomorrow, you mean, to make it balanced?  I feel the people who run SO are best placed to decide what should happen on SO.  Perhaps you should ask your gay friends (you have some, right?) what they think of a website changing its logo for a few hours to celebrate a positive change in the law.

Comment: @asgs "..keep the focus off...devote our time...other places on Internet"  What are you talking about? They changed the logo, not you.

Comment: @Alex see asgs's comment: in the world discrimination and social issues are not just limited to gay discrimination. And I don't need to go that far to disturb my gay friends: I also think changing a logo is not a big deal. But I also think that SO logo is not Google's Doodle.

Comment: @PietroSaccardi There are other forms of discrimination; this is an all too rare celebration of the success of freedom and justice over bigotry and stupidness in just one sphere.  I'm sure other successes would be celebrated also.

Comment: Closing my account due to your showing support for the Supreme Court's unlawful overthrow of the Constitution.

Comment: @dalewking if you still get to read this after you close your account, the US Constitution was a first draft, which is amended from time to time as bugs are identified.

Comment: @trichoplax and I have no trouble with amending the constitiution. If people feel that the marriage should be extended to people based on sexual behavior then by all means follow the process and do it through an amendment. This ruling bypasses that process and says states have no rights, that there is no more a right to freedom of religion.

No matter which way you feel on the matter Stack Overflow (and the other companies I will no longer do business with) have no business expressing an opinion either way.

Comment: I'd argue that SOPA is way more relevant to SO than gay marriage.

Comment: Fun fact, if you post a question on SO that is just remotely opinionated it will be blocked almost immediately. not so much for opinionated logo changes, apparently. talk about SO being community driven and fact based...

Comment: I agree with you but the creator of the whole thing wants it and won't listen to anyone else because "some people" have given him crap so he looks at every one and everything with the same glasses that is "prejudice" and "hatred". I'm really disappointed because apparently some personal opinions are more relevant than others.

Comment: I think people need to relax. It hurts nothing to give the logo some color to in honor of social progress. + 1

Comment: @BobHorn SO, although saying they represent an international community proves that it represents only the USA. Every exception that is made on SO policy relates to some social progress made inside USA. This is why I don't agree with the logo change. There is a lot of social progress in other parts of the world, and btw the number of europeans on SO is greater than the number of americans. but don't worry, we are used to in your face attitudes by american companies.

Comment: @Kyralessa I totally agree with you; the world in general is turning a completely blind eye to what ISIS is doing, and that needs to change.

Comment: @Alex by changing the website (even if it's a logo) you visit often for other purposes, you're indirectly infusing something into someone who doesn't "need" it. What we are all saying is changing logo for matters irrelevent to this site is not appreciable. There are things like Google's Doodle which can express the joy and happiness on this judgment. Hope you got this point. Otherwise, I'm sorry if I hurt someone's feelings.

Comment: FactorMystic, I understand your point of view, this shouldn't be used for supporting/fighting political issues. However, the logo change is a light way of showing some support. "Why support this particular cause and not others?". Imagine this news headline: "ACME donates 10000$ to Social Org. X": would you say "why donate to Social Org. X and not others?". My point is, you can't show support/be against/help everything. Even people who live to help others will only be able to reach a small percentage of the world, so this seems, in the end, positive as it is ultimately supporting **tolerance**

Comment: Yeah, it's not a matter do you agree or not; it's just not a place to state such things so please go spread your love somewhere else.

Comment: @BobHorn: "I think people need to relax." Dude, the gay marriage thing was over the internet for the past 2 years or so. So now the law has passed, it is time to let it go. It is a fundamental right, so if anything you guys should be deeply ashamed it took so long to grant it. The law should've been created century ago. Besides, there are non-american users, so USA political shenanigans have nothing to do with them, don't you think? Not to mention that it has no connection whatsoever to programming.

Comment: Agree, it's really irrelevant. And agree or not. Not everybody will like this.

Comment: @gkon exactly because not everybody will like this is why they should do it, if you are not in favor of this then I would rather to not see you on any of the sites of stackoverflow, props to these guys for caring more about love than a few more users on their site!

Comment: SO has taken pride in the fact that the it's all about the participants: the askers and answerers are the ones who drive the site, give it direction, and make it successful. The decision to change the logo to reflect a contentious political position gives lie to that claim. The logo represents SO and SO claims to represent me, a participant. But at present, it's misrepresenting me.

Answer (score 328):

I disagree with the proposed temporary logo change. Why? Well it's simple, this website is all about programming, not about equality of people, equality of animals, the rights of whales, climate change, equality of religion, human rights, politics etc.

If you're happy about the options for gay couples to get married, well be happy about that. I don't dislike gays, I'm just totally not interested in the news. So I don't want this to get shoved down my throat. I would also expect a website focused on programming, to stay neutral when it comes to opinions about unrelated topics.

Besides this, where is the border? When should the logo be changed and when shouldn't it?

**Let me give you a short example:**

The Urgenda Foundation filed the "Climate Case" against the Dutch government. The Dutch government was defeated in this case. This never happened before, it's a revolutionary thing, major news in the Netherlands! Just like gay marriage is for the Americans. So why change the logo for the American news? And not for the Dutch news? I understand the fact that the SE office is in America. But I think, because this website is internationally used, the logo should not be changed (or only be changed for the Americans, but I would not encourage that).

http://www.urgenda.nl/en/climate-case/

Some things, to think about:

- Should the logo also be changed if IS is defeated?
- Should the logo be changed if the same happens in another country?
- Should the logo be changed if Whale protection is finally be taken serious?
- Should the logo be changed when many other endangered animals like tigers finally have "the right to speak"?
- Pink ribbon (fight against breast cancer) logo?
- Awareness for child abuse?
- Progress in woman rights around the world?
- Why wasn't to logo changed when "je suis charlie' or similar things where trending? (This one is especially about human rights)
- Etc.

Well it feels like I'm wasting time, since everybody seems to be blinded by the news, and forgets that topics like these would normally be off-topic. What are we becoming? Some kind of social media discussion platform, based on opinions?

Back to programming...

Comment: It may of happened in america but it is worldwide news, a large government has just ruled in equality which can only open the doors for other countries. For the record, I am not gay, and I support your right to an opinion, as well as others just as equally

Comment: @Sayse, the Dutch news is also worldwide, or at least for Europe. As it will affect the Climate Conference in Paris. And gives many opportunities for similar cases by foundations in many other countries in Europe.

Comment: What is it with the phrase "shoved down my throat"? It's a tiny 40x40 pixel logo. It has literally no impact on your ability to use the site, whatsoever. It doesn't change the sites behaviour or functionality in any way.

Comment: Hmm, I think the idea of changing logos for USA IP addresses is pretty feasible - it's an USA's court that makes a decision in question, so they can freely celebrate. But you're right in "I don't want this to be shoved down my throat" - me too.

Comment: @Meagar, it may seem small, but as soon as I browsed to Stackoverflow I noticed it immediately (and I immediately knew what it was about). Then I started to search for the reason and found this topic.

Comment: _"Should the logo be changed if the same happens in another country?"_ I'm sure by your answer you would think it would be a bad idea, but personally, I think it would be a brilliant show of international support if this was done for each country from now on that legalizes gay marriage. Especially considering the several international employees working for SE.

Comment: @Kendra, the support for gay marriage is very very bad in Russia. Would the Russian Stackoverflow users approve?

Comment: I feel like one of the employees mentioned Russia at one point, and Italy as well. So I'm pretty sure at least some of them would.

Comment: @Rolfツ "I was able to notice that this exists because I looked closely, and went out of my way to follow up on it" is not even close to "this is being shoved down my throat".

Comment: @Sayse, I agree. But remember it's just an example.

Comment: Uhh, no it won't, none of those are US centric, none of those a *setting a precedent the world needs*.

Comment: `tigers finally have "the right to speak"?` lolwut?

Comment: @MartinSmith In terms of protection laws and compliance with the law.

Comment: Some people just wanna suck the joy out of everything.

Comment: Some people think murica is the only country in the world

Comment: Not everyone will share the opinion that this is joyful news, its that simple. Personally I'd rather to stay neutral but it seems that certain ones feel its alright to force their opinions on others I'm just surprised at the source. Poor judgement call from SO.

Comment: Can't add this to Moosemans answer because its been locked *(surprise surprise)*. @meagar That is not fair and by stating it you are clearly showing your bias. This is why these types of issues should be kept to social/political/religious forums not SO.

Comment: http://registerguard.com/rg/news/local/32947906-75/eugene-teens-get-their-day-in-court-in-climate-case.html.csp

Comment: This week was full of all kinds of news. But while everyone was distracted, the Senate passed TPP under the radar. Can it be even more obvious?

Comment: @Lankymart I deleted several answers when they strayed off-topic, both for and against. It had nothing to do with their content.

Comment: @meagar You also made quite a few derogatory comments of your own, with a strong bias towards a particular view. The fact you are doing this with a less then neutral view of the topic to me is both unfair and disappointing.

Comment: @Lankymart My comments were on-topic and none of them were derogatory. Independently of whatever views I hold on the subject, I cleaned up the thread as countless off-topic and crap answers were posted, as often happens with extremely popular questions. If you have any specific examples of how I acted inappropriately, send them to the community team, I'm not debating this with you further.

Comment: @Rolfツ The usual SO logo, the one that's been displayed every day for years, is rendered in orange and black. How much more support for the Dutch do you want?!

Comment: @Lankymart As I said, I'm not debating further, this is not a suitable place for extended discussion. Please take it up with the community team.

Comment: @Rolfツ, The climate change is not just "Netherland news". It's **world** news. It's the first court case **in the world** in which a state is held accountable in this way.

Comment: I agree with this answer. As much as I am happy for this news, there are several examples of more important news items which did *not* get any coverage / indication on SO. I don't want to offend anyone, but gay marriage legalisation is nothing compared to some news which deals with thousands of deaths. Furthermore, this issue is too localised and cannot be reproduced in other countries. I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 285):

I am a straight non-American. Today's Supreme Court decision has nothing to do with me, you'd think. But it's still a huge thing for me because I believe that if I can enjoy both the comfort and the legal benefits of a happy marriage, it is a disgrace if another couple just as happily in love cannot, purely because they are gay.

As we Europeans do, I sometimes tend to have smug thoughts about how the USA is so backwards in one way or the other. Well, today they showed me, because unlike my American coworkers, I live in a country whose head of government is on record saying she is "uneasy" about the idea of marriage equality.

I hope that today's event triggers a change in the remaining strongholds of those antiquated attitudes, in Germany and in many other places. Very well knowing that there are many more problems to be solved, but still, this is a big step.

And that's why I believe that it's a global event that has a chance to impact, in the long run, each and every person in the world. And that includes all the programmers.

My vote is, "Hell yeah".

Comment: Hell Yeah! Me Too!

Comment: Bravo @balpha, you speak for me too.

Comment: The fact that people downvote such a positive answer like this is sad.

Comment: This answer maxed out my vote count for the day. :)

Comment: @balpha for Bundeskanzler!

Comment: @BobHorn there unfortunately will always be intolerance.

Comment: @Matt  Like when people have *"...thoughts about how the USA is so backwards in one way or the other..."*?

Comment: A very polite and British "hell yeah" from me too. Here in the UK, marriage equality was brought in by a conservative Prime Minister, to only minor grumbles in his party.

Comment: Things can change quickly, just look at how far Ireland have come in a generation.

Comment: @halfer I was impressed how it went. He has my respect more than ever I have to say.

Comment: @Tim, he might need to work on his discrimination against the poor, but hey, no-one's perfect `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer Yes, fair point. I lack the... age and experience to see all these, especially with a more privileged upbringing. He seems to try though, with the minimum-wage-below-tax-threshold stuffs.

Comment: Could not have said it better myself @balpha!

Comment: This answer is totally off-topic. I support gay marriage too. But if we should have a change in logo, then we should have a change in logo for other social issues too.

Comment: @dan-klasson I have answered the question and given my reasoning. You may disagree with it, but how does that make my answer "totally off-topic"?

Comment: @BobHorn, I downvote not because it is positive or not, but because I disagree. In the years of SO, I have downvoted many positive, yet off-topic or misguided posts. It's not about positivity.

Comment: @balpha: My bad. I thought you meant you voted for gay marriage. Then your answer should be a comment. Because the only thing in your answer was your opinion on gay marriage and had nothing to do with whether the logo should be changed.

Comment: @balpha would you expect SO to change logo when gay people will have equal rights in Germany? or in Romania?

Comment: This small logo change is either an abuse or a green light for pushing environmental/social/political agendas through SO. Considering that SO community is mostly intentional and the current court decision only affects a minority of a minority of a minority then it will be highly hypocritical/unfair not to promote for e.g. environmental or internet freedom causes that effect everyone on the planet or on the internet.

Answer (score 202):

Irrespective of the validity/significance/importance (or lack thereof) of any developments in the political/social arena, Stackoverflow has got nothing to do with it. Stackoverflow has a specific mission and getting involved with politics or good or evil in life isn't part of it.

Comment: Wrong. See my answer. This ruling directly affects SE.

Comment: @Qix directly affects their payroll and HR perhaps, but it doesn't affect SE as a whole.

Comment: You forget culture. Culture is a big thing.

Comment: @Qix You say "...literally the last oppressed demographic of America...." Are you kidding me? What about atheists? What about minority rights, racism etc? Look at the list of people who are most unfavorably perceived and there are other groups of people who have it even worse. All I'm saying is that discrimnation doesn't just affect just one group but many and we need to stick to Stackoverflow's mission.

Comment: Everyone has same legal rights now... Not sure how that's up for debate.

Comment: @Qix whatever culture shift there may be has no bearing on how SE/SO operates. Business as usual for us trying to fix indentations and typos on someone's question.

Comment: @Trobbins if you think that's all SE does, I don't think you have the bearings to be able to weigh in on such a discussion.

Comment: @Qix I was being facetious, don't be quick to judge

Comment: @Trobbins You know what else has no bearing on how SE/SO operates? The color of their logo. So let it change and move on. That doesn't prevent you from participating in the same way you always have.

Comment: @BobHorn If it has no bearing then let's just move on and not change anything.

Comment: @uhsarp I'm fine if it doesn't change and life goes on. I'm also fine with changing it and life goes on. How about we all be the same way and be fine with either approach? Let's not get all bent out of shape about it because the logo might change. It doesn't affect us either way. So if folks want to enjoy what happened, let them.

Comment: @Bob I wasn't making a stand on the debate one way or another. I couldn't care less what SO/SE's logo was

Comment: The right to marriage is not "politics". It has been politicised, but like marriage between anyone else it is simply a fundamental recognition in the eyes of a law that a couple is indeed a couple.

Comment: @Qix You obviously have a very clear agenda that doesn't mean though that anyone else's opinions are any less valid. That is the beauty of neutrality, today SO has crossed that line.

Comment: It hasn't crossed a line.

Comment: @Qix It clearly has. People should be free to accept same sex marriage as people should be free to reject it. That is after all what being neutral means. Placing logos or banners etc that advocates a particular socio-political agenda flies in the face of that. Plus the bias here to a particular agenda and shooting down those with a different view is frankly not what I expected from SO.

Comment: You're welcome to use another top Q&A programming site.

Comment: @Gorb That reasoning is simply wrong. Marriage is **not** simply about "being a couple". Why should the state even care at all whether X likes Y? What's so wrong about the fight for these "rights" is that they are simply destroying the meaning of marriage and making it something useless that doesn't actually have any meaning left. They replace marriage with a piece of paper were the state recognizes "X loves Y so they pay less taxes and have a bit of benefits". The facts are that **science** tells us male != female and male + female = offsprings( = cellular of society != X likes Y)

Comment: @Qix So your saying if you don't happen to share our beliefs /views you're not welcome on SO, nice message! This is why neutrality is so important, without it communities are divided. This is a terrible attitude to have extremely disappointed with the forcefulness of this agenda.

Comment: Whatever you think you believe about what StackOverflow "is", you can't pull the plug, can you?  The domain is not registered to you.  It's all rental space.  And the guy renting it to you has something to celebrate today.  Get over it.

Comment: @Bakuriu science also tells us that homosexuality is common in many other animal species - besides homo sapiens.

Comment: You summoned science - to prove what? That 2 male or 2 female humans cannot have offspring? Humans realized that, long before other scientific facts, before they knew earth is round. Marriage has always been a social contract and society and its values changes. I guess you have a different view on the meaning of marriage.

Answer (score 154):

Do not mix social issues with programming issues. There is no need for politics to be included on this website. IF you want politics, go to politics.stackexchange.com. Whether someone is a sandwich, gay, or has three penises, it shouldn't matter; the entire thing is a red herring.

EDIT: **Because OP did not mention this in the original post**, gay marriage is now legal nation-wide in my particular country. I did not know this.

Comment: This is not politics. This is about equality and people. Finally, *it is no longer politics*!

Comment: @Tim: This is a **programming/coding** website.

Comment: For people. People who's lives have just changed? Why can't we celebrate the people here?

Comment: I invite you to read [Joel's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297871/865899). "The point is that allowing EVERYONE to marry IS the neutral position."

Comment: Er, because I didn't realize that gay marriage is now legal nation-wide. Maybe OP should mention that in his OP. @abbyhairboat

Comment: @DonLarynx have you visited any other site today? It's like the top 3 trending twitter topics worldwide...

Comment: @DonLarynx you might want to turn on the tv....

Comment: @Qix: I don't care for current events. I'm all for this, but **OP needs to mention the context in the original post.** P.S. I don't watch TV.

Comment: @MoH. - At *work*?

Comment: @MoH. Not everyone watches TV/Twitter.

Comment: @DonLarynx I edited it. I agree.

Comment: Also, some workplaces block social networks.

Comment: First place I heard about this was here on SO,  and then checked Reddit on my phone to verify.  Cut the guy some slack.

Comment: If I like ponies and create a website for professional surgeons, should I change the logo to a pony at any time?

Comment: @rr-: If you want to, you can do. It's your website. You can set the logo to whatever you want.

Comment: @Tim But what do marriages have to do with programming? I'd understand if the law concerned mostly programmers, but it applies to everyone so it's even less relevant to this specific site.

Comment: @Tim: It's literally not. I don't give a damn if the government sees two people as married or single. It's none of their business. Keep government out of the bedroom.

Comment: @Tim: You said it was relevant  "to literally everyone alive today". Does one truly need to explain to you that it very clearly isn't relevant to those who don't care if government recognized marriage or not, or to those who do not wish to marry?

Comment: @Tim: Oh, so now because one hopes for all to be free of government intrusion into their social lives, they're uncaring of others? Stop the H8. ...and how does it back up *what* argument?

Comment: @Tim: I never said it was hurting me. How could it be if it's not relevant to me? Obviously there are gay programmers... there are straight ones too. What's your point?

Comment: @Tim: Because I don't think it's a good idea for StackOverflow to change its logo for the sake of something that's only relevant to some. Why are you trying to pit straight people against gays here? Your hostility is palpable.

Comment: @Tim: But it's really not. It's specifically for gay people. Again, for me it's mostly about adding more government to our personal lives, so it's relevant to me in that specific sense. I'd rather see government just not care if two (or three or twelve) people are married (or single). So it's about inclusion of some people into an institution but not all people. Greatest way for it to be truly equal is to get rid of it since it's entirely unnecessary anyway.

Comment: @Tim: Government marriage would be largely irrelevant to people if there were not certain benefits or rights attached. Anyone who feels they don't fit in to how government defines marriage (say like a polygamist, someone who wishes to remain single or someone who has a certain religious objection) has to forego those benefits. As long as marriage exists as a government institution, there will be parameters around it for inclusion, meaning there will be people excluded.

Comment: @Tim: People of religion can be married without the government's "blessing". I think people just don't even think about it since it's such a long standing tradition for government to be involved. People who are religions can get married before their minister (or whatever religious leader). People who are not can make it entirely contractual if they wish. Other people can define whatever social structure they want. All of the above can be treated truly equally if government doesn't care about their personal lives.

Comment: @LyeFish Trust me, I know. I'm planning on being married, in a church by a minister. With a government official there. Why? Because I want to. I want as many people to know and acknowledge my marriage.

Comment: @Tim: Fair enough though I doubt you'd believe your marriage will be any less special without the government involved. Fact remains that government does exclude from associated benefits those who don't fit into its definition of marriage. It will never truly be an institution of equality until government steps aside.

Comment: Hehe, where do I vote to move this question to politics.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 83):

By adding this logo and promoting it like a declaration sign, StackOverflow is taking the side of a social cause and a favor that many might agree or disagree (primarily opinion based), in America or around the world.

Based on the site's rules, if a question or answer is opinion-based, it is flagged for closing. Judging by its community rules, the nature of the site is to be opinion-neutral, no matter who has the opinion. Furthermore, StackOverflow should not express particular favors. It is a community-based coding Q&A Site and should express those who agree, along with those who disagree equally.

Comment: Vote to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Community based, yes. But the community does not own the site.

Comment: There's a difference between taking a position and disrespecting. The flag does not disrespect anyone.

Comment: @Bart With all the respect, I disagree. The answer is not opinion-based, but based on the site's rules.

Comment: @Sklivvz the word "express" might make more sense here.

Comment: This isn't user-submitted content to be voted on by the community. Stack Exchange is a company, and they own Stack Overflow, and they're based in the US. They are completely entitled to change their logo.

Comment: @meagar Of course they are, but the point is that the site is driven by the community, am I wrong?

Comment: @NickL.  No, it's driven by the people who own it, who are free to accept as much or as little community input as they want. They have historically accepted **a lot**, and continue to do so.

Comment: Just because I suggested it, and 300+ people agree doesn't mean they were forced into it.

Comment: The *original* logo was [designed and selected by the community](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest/) with the founders exercising just a little bit of editorial oversight, @NickL. I'd say that's probably a good model to follow for any major changes, and this isn't too much of a deviation. That said, I really hope we don't start doing this every week.

Comment: My point is that the site *should* be neutral. This is not about my opinion or any others'. It is about a whole community.

Comment: what questions is the logo itself asking and/or answering?

Comment: @NickL. it is neutral. It's neutral for equal rights.

Comment: @Tim with all the respect, it is not opinion-neutral. Someone might agree or disagree with it and still be members of the community.

Comment: @NickL. Fair enough, but what is represents is. If people feel offended by it, then I have to say I feel sorry for them...

Comment: @Tim the topic is controversial. Those offended could also say they feel sorry for you, this is the point. Even by saying that it is rights-neutral can find people not agreeing. And SO is not a place for such controversial topics, it is a coding Q&A site.

Comment: @NickL. It is a coding Q&A site for Humans by Humans. Is it really so bad that nothing human is allowed through. And people ask why my activity is elsewhere on the network.

Comment: @Tim "dura lex sed lex " - the law is hard, but it is the law. The rules are specific and are decided from Humans. And, apart from that, you have Humans that *do not agree* with this for each one having his/her own reasons but being a part of the community at the same time.

Comment: @NickL. and this time, the rules have been relaxed. Now loosen up, it's a celebration.

Comment: @Tim, please read the discussion again. It is not about me loosening up, it is about a community following some rules. Wishes for the best.

Comment: @meagar What nonsensical reasoning! The site is community driven without the community you have nothing. Accept input? Seriously?? They **need** input and for that reason should have more respect for all community members.

Comment: @NickL. It's a well balanced argument but I'm afraid *balance* is something these guys are not interested in. You could argue until you are blue in the face, try and form a structured argument for SO being neutral and the response will be *"losen up it's a celebratation!"*.

Answer (score 81):

I think this court decision is a huge step forward, but it's just that: a court decision. SO is not (was not) a platform for the endorsement of court decisions. From Google searches, it looks like American acceptance of gay marriage is at about 60%. Whatever you think of whether that number should get higher or lower as the years go by (I'd like to see it higher), it still means that 40% of Americans would see the endorsement of a court decision that they don't agree with if they go to SO (NB: the population who's actually likely to go to SO is probably skewed toward the 60%).

No matter what I think of any given political change, it's disconcerting to see a neutral programming Q&A site take a stance on a polarizing political issue. What will happen to the next big court decision that affects many people? If, e.g., abortion is ruled to be a fundamental human right, will the SO logo turn into a hospital with a car driving away from it? Or if fetuses are ruled to be legally protected from abortion, will the logo change to a healthy fetus in a rectangular womb? If the courts rule in favor of nationwide CCW reciprocity, will the overflowing stack be painted yellow to represent a chamber with a stream of brass flying out of it? What happens on SO if Ramadan is declared an official national holiday?

Will the responses to this question produce some meta-effect on the posts of people who voiced their disagreement with the logo change? What about the people who stayed quiet because they felt uncomfortable disagreeing with the majority? Unfortunately in this case, making some people feel more comfortable will mean making other people feel less comfortable, and I can't see the justification for that boiling down to anything but vengeance, selfishness, or schadenfreude. I thought SO wasn't about politics, but it looks like - today at least - SO is a place that will make those against gay marriage feel like they don't belong, even if they have programming questions or answers. And that, not this ruling on gay marriage, is what doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: "Is it truly inclusive if it excludes those against inclusiveness?" I wasn't prepared for this level of profoundness.

Comment: I agree with this sentiment, but based on the voting on the question and moderator answers (which is how we judge feature-requests), there's no reason to not implement the "feature".

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I just wanted to program things but today I was like, "what". I'll make sure to make similar feature request on next GPL anniversary, it will be way more relevant and yet I bet it'll get turned down with a massive "slam".

Comment: Oops, will edit; thank you. :)

Comment: @Tim, you raise a good point - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Github also changed their logo. While not as strict, other programming sites have taken part in this movement. Not saying we have to do what everyone else does, but one day probably won't exclude too many programmers for long. Cheers

Comment: uhh.. christmas *is* a national holiday, in the US, where the SE is based

Comment: I didn't know it was official. How disappointing. I'll change it to a different religious holiday.

Comment: @BoltClock, is atheism a form of faith/religion? Is a blank whiteboard less neutral than one that contains messages encouraging neutrality? Is a `null`/`nil`/`None` reference more empty than a variable that hasn't been assigned?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This is an excellent, well thought out answer and I completely agree with the sentiment. I feel we may be in the minority though judging by the vote bashing *aka The Meta Effect*.

Comment: @Lankymart, my understanding is that the Meta effect refers to downvotes _on a user's regular SO posts_ from Meta users seeking justice (which I think may have happened to me, but there were no clues such as "I'm downvoting this good answer because you said something dumb on Meta" comments, so it's probably mere paranoia).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It may not apply to meta content but the principle is the same. Also if votes on meta are just to show disagreement with an idea or view then why do highly voted down answers get greyed out and unable to be voted on?

Comment: @Lankymart I believe some got locked because of the volume of comments.

Comment: @justcool393 Possibly but I'm not being funny but what did they expect? It's extremely shortsighted.

Comment: _NB: the population who's actually likely to go to SO is probably skewed toward the 60%_ - do you evidence for that?  Given the age of most of the programmers that I have worked with in different companies (usually under 30, 90% under 40) I would guess support could easily be 80-90%  but that too is a guess.  But it relates to survey that show that support in those age groups is generally *much* higher. Some older folks are a bit more enlightened and in support though.  I like to think I'm one of them.

Comment: @Lankymart looks like only the question gor locked. all answers can be voted/commented on

Comment: Isn't Ramadan like 30 days long? If it were declared a [global] public holiday, what would happen on SO is a really interesting question. My prediction is that the Java tag would grind to a halt and the NodeJS tag would have its most active month ever.

Comment: You sir, are my hero,  "If the courts rule in favor of nationwide CCW reciprocity, will the overflowing stack be painted yellow to represent a chamber with a stream of brass flying out of it?"

Answer (score 69):

I don't know what all this gay marriage stuff is; I just like rainbows.

Let's do it.

---

**This is a *huge* day for an oppressed demographic in America**. StackOverflow, being HQ'd in New York, is directly affected as now they can guarantee their widely diverse employee-base gross benefits that aren't catered to their non-fabulous (but equally awesome) coworkers.

[Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=gay+marriage) is doing it. [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23LoveWins) is doing it. Many, many sites are doing it.

So why should *we*, as a programming Q&A site, do it??

Because there is such a thing as a gay programmer. StackExchange was created by one.

In the words of Joel Spolsky, *bye Felicia*.

---

It is done.
[image: LoveOverflow]

Comment: (full disclosure - gay American here, quite happy about it)

Comment: Not sure of "*last* oppressed demographic" but +1 on the rest.

Comment: Pretty sure several other demographic groups could consider themselves oppressed.

Comment: +1 but definitely not the last oppressed demographic

Comment: Edited; obviously is arguable. But thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @KasraRahjerdi - just woke up, can't spell today.

Comment: @Qix always have faith in the Stack Overflow community to have pedantic fixes ready to go :)

Comment: @FactorMystic - PHP developers, for example.  Maybe we can have a 'PHP Day' soon?

Comment: @MartinJames PHP devs are only oppressed by the language they're using. ;)

Comment: `I don't know what all this gay marriage stuff is; I just like rainbows.` Hell, add a unicorn and some pancakes and we could even keep it permanently. It fits SO pretty well in my opinion.

Comment: You could change the image to one with the tooltip :)

Comment: @falsarella will do.

Comment: *"Google is doing it. Twitter is doing it. Many, many sites are doing it."* ...and if we all follow the lemmings ...

Comment: "Google is doing it"... but only if you search for a very specific topic, that's different than just displaying it for any topic.

Comment: @Rolfツ splitting hairs here. Github is doing it too. Almost every mainstream website is doing it.

Comment: i'm not gay, gay marriage and america is none of my business, but I'm totally against marrying someone other than a developer :p no java or .net developers otherwise I'd rather stay single :p

Comment: add a unicorn and some pancakes?

Comment: Strongly as I agree with the "Marry whomever you love" sentiment, Jessica Alba doesn't seem agreeable with the idea...

Comment: Github is doing it too!

Comment: But the logo is not colored as a rainbow. The rainbow has seven main colors. Where is aqua (light blue, RGB: 0,255,255) between green and blue in the rainbow-like-colored logo?

Answer (score 46):

Since it is past end of day EST, this answer is largely moot, but it seems apt.

I am perhaps reminded of when Steve Jobs died. And then Dennis Ritchie *AND* John McCarthy died in short order. There was an announcement for Steve Jobs, it was in the top banner. There was no eulogy for the other two. The conclusion that the SO team made was that this was a mistake.

My point is that events, no matter how momentous, do not belong in the icon any more than they belong in the notification.

Answer (score 42):

Millions of people seem to care what the daily Google Doodle is. In fact, *actual* news outlets report them as *actual* news! They aren't always controversial, but they are often about something I either never knew about, or never cared about. I can choose to learn more or not. I can choose to care - or not.

Same thing with this. We could stand to put out regular reminders that we're part of a bigger world - without needing to be the one standing on the soapbox. Individuals can embrace the opportunity to learn, and sometimes celebrate - or not.

---

For the record, I'm a *North*-American male, hetero and in a 3-decade long committed Christian relationship. For me, none of that has a bearing on what others should be allowed to do. I love many friends and family who do not share my beliefs, choices, or orientation. I hurt for anyone marginalized for theirs.

The US court's decision has come 10 years after Canada's - and I'm glad that it did finally come. I hope it will continue to build support for gender-ish equality - and that we don't all sit back and think it's done.

In her speech at my son's High School commencement ceremony yesterday, a prominent local official recalled their production of [The Laramie Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laramie_Project) as her highlight of the graduates' years in their school. "As a person who has faced discrimination and challenges for my own sexual orientation", I'm paraphrasing, "I'm proud of the community in this school that not only allowed and supported a dramatic investigation into bigotry and hatred against gays, but which actively promotes dialog and inclusion."

For me, that statement was as impactful as the milestone of having a successful graduate. I grew up surrounded by mistrust and prejudice, and although I was straight, was the target of "Anti-Faggot" verbal and physical abuse. There is no room for that in any enlightened society.

When my son and his friends learned and performed that play - reflecting the whole range of genders & orientations in their school - it built stronger relationships, and personal pride for everyone involved. I think that matters. But that's beside the point.

In the end, whether we have a rainbow logo for a while celebrating support for a judgment we may or may not personally embrace, a yellow one in support of soldiers fighting wars we may or may not agree with, a pink one in support of fighting cancers many of us will never have - is it really so disruptive to be worth the angst?

Comment: And speaking of Google: they don't have a doodle for this (yet), but they did put "YouTube and Google are [proud to celebrate marriage equality.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSiehK2asbI) #ProudtoLove" under the search box.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yet you will notice a lack of change of icon on Facebook.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Who said anything about Facebook?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Facebook is another major digital company, but it has not changed its icon.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Nobody said they did. This answer talked about the Google Doodle, and so did I. I think you're reading too much into my comment.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The Doodle didn't change. It is more subtle.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I know the Doodle didn't change. That's why I said "they don't have a doodle for this."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot How I read this: your point, "look at this company which has changed! That is important." My point, "But this other company did not. Is is telling, too."

Comment: Rathole. The point of my mention of the doodle was that while some people can and do pay attention to it, others can ignore it yet still use the offered service. People can choose to ignore a modified SO logo, and still use SO for it's intended purpose.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: https://www.facebook.com/celebratepride

Comment: Hey - you've unwittingly provided the solution which will make everyone happy! Just change the StackOverflow logo every day ala Google. Call it the Soodle. Then no-one has to continue arguing about "why only this one time?"

Answer (score 38):

Joel - I get it, it's your site and this is a big event - but this is a slippery slope. I'm all for the Supreme Court decision, but now what? Are you going to change the logo for something affecting women's rights outside of America? Are you going to change the logo for victims of a global catastrophe? Are you going to change the logo when another event happens? How far will it go? I agree with the decision and I think it's awesome - but I think you've set a bad precedent with this for a global community. If SO endorses one issue, it must start to endorse all of them or risk questions like "why this event, but not this one?".

Luckily, the change wasn't intrusive, but just be careful not to muddy the waters. You own Stack Overflow, but it's bigger than you or me now - it's grown to transcend culture, creed, location, everything. I think that Stack Overflow endorsements have the potential to reverse that, even if it's in good spirit.

Comment: Have you even read his answer?

Comment: Google does this kind of thing [all the time](https://www.google.com/doodles/). What's the harm?

Comment: @Tim I read the answer, yes.

Comment: @200_success Google does this type of thing all the time. SO doesn't. My opinion - either you do it all the time, for everything, as Google does, or you can't really do it at all. I don't mind SO swinging one way or the other, but I'd rather not see SO cherry-pick occasionally, if that makes sense; I think it has the potential to undermine what SO has become. (The community content here is a good example.)

Comment: Who said it has to be "all or nothing"? Five year old kids ask "Why did he get a cookie but not me? It's unfair!" Life is unfair, nothing new there. It does not have to be all or nothing. No one is preventing you from creating a meta question whenever you want the logo changed.

Comment: _If SO endorses one issue, it must start to endorse all of them_ This is a false dilemma. _or risk questions like_  Look, there is someone on Meta asking us to require people to comment when down-voting every other day. All you have to do the 2+ times it gets asked is to mark it as a duplicate and move on.

Comment: @200_success Google can be and is wrong in many cases and that's OK. People work there and people make mistakes but inferring that something is correct just because Google did it is a fallacy or more clearly argument from authority which contradicts the very foundations on which SO was built.

Comment: @matcheek How's this for an argument from authority: It's their site, and they can make their logo look however they want it to. Deal with it or leave. Don't let the door hit 'ya.

Comment: @ChrisBaker Let's forget for a moment that in no way you are responding to my argument -objectiveness, not authority laid the foundations of SO, and focus on what you wrote.The power of SO comes from the joint efforts of professionals around the globe, not from the owners of SO - they merely let it happen. This single act set the precedence in the software-focused community to support a particular social cause what inadvertently resulted in strong divide. From now on people will be bringing their social causes to the table and SO will have to act on them or admit its bias and intolerance

Comment: Or, do what they want because it is their site. I think you're over-estimating the number of people that care either way. Apathy is powerful -- it's the reason most of our problems exist. A majority of the users won't notice the logo, understand the context, or participate in the inevitable complaining. Those apathetic users, combined with contributors like me who rightly suppose SE can do what they want, comprise a vast majority of the community. I'm not saying you can't complain, but if there's any division, it's *because* you're complaining, not because there's a real problem

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg : "Life is unfair, nothing new there." ... So the bottom line of your comment is "Don't stand up to / comment on things you don't think are appropriate but just ignore them because life is unfair anyway"? In my opinion life should be fair and anyone should be free and encouraged to point out if he/she thinks that something is unfair. The logo change says "we're in favour of equal opportunities for all couples" but it also says "we don't treat social / political issues equally". The logo change is to celebrate equalization by the discrimination of other topics.

Comment: @Pixelchemist a) It's funny you bring up the fairness again, because as you said, this logo change is all about fairness and equality. b) As I said, no one is preventing you from creating a meta post for whatever issue you want. I believe this logo change got through because of the many upvotes vs. the many downvotes. If you can accomplish the same thing another time, I think it's possible that there will be more such logo changes.

Comment: Totally agree.. IMO Joel is just looking at what happens in US and supports it(or sometimes maybe not), while the majority of the users coming to this site are from outside US.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg a) That is my point: Celebrate fairness by potential unfairness is not quite THE idea. b) Even if every logo change request that had an equal (or higher) upvotes vs downvotes ratio or number on meta would be shown on the main site (I doubt it, actually), I don't think you'd end up treating issues equally. The site blog is a place for things affecting SE itself (and for the current topic as well since one can argue that SE is affected).

Comment: @Pixelchemist Where's this potential unfairness you're talking about? About treating issues differently? I've told you already, nothing is preventing you from creating another meta post. I think that another logo change can happen if you manage to gather a whole bunch of up-votes. I think creating another round of massive upvoting for a logo-change is unlikely though, but definitely not impossible. And as long as you *don't even try* doing that, I don't think you really have any "unfairness" to complain about.

Comment: This is the old relative privation argument. How can we focus on X when Y is happening? If you talk about Z, then you have to talk about Q because that's bad/unfair/wrong too. It's a logical fallacy, and an enormous waste of time and energy.

Answer (score 32):

I am no longer active on this site I thought where a Q&A site about programming. **IMO** this site/company has made an abusive move flagging (literally) its sociopolitical agenda.

I am **absolutely not** accepting being used as part of or associated with ***any*** political or social agenda ***without consent***.

> [...] Couldn't be more relevant to Stack Overflow.
>   - Joel Spolsky

In that case the site has been dishonest at best. This "relevance" should have been stated clearly *before* users signed up to what seems to be a technical programming oriented site, so they can choose to not being used as part of this or any other agenda (which it must be if it "couldn't be more relevant"...).

(And now, lets see *tolerance* in practice...!)

Comment: "I am **absolutely not** accepting ... (And now, lets see tolerance in practice...!)"

Comment: Okay then. Bye byes for the weekend. How are we forcing you to do *anything*?

Comment: If you absolutely can't stand that small little speck of rainbow in your corner, just "boycott" the site until it's gone. No one's making you stay and contribute. If it bothers you that badly that the owners and maintainers of the site wish to express their joy about something that directly affects them in a small and non-in-your-face way, then walk away from the site. As I said in a comment on an answer below, how is this is any way speaking for you if you have no control over the changes made by the team?

Comment: The relevance is a corollary of SO's openness to all people and indifference to their nonprogramming features, as explained in Joel's post.

Comment: I don't see your name on the company roster there bud. Stack doesn't need your consent for anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what your last sentence is about: Downvotes are not a show of intolerance, they're a show of disagreement. People *are* still allowed to disagree with each other.

Comment: @Oded if you don't know the difference between accepting and tolerance then I feel sorry for you.

Comment: @Kendra it is about more than a "small little speck of rainbow in your corner".

Comment: absolutely not accepting == intolerant.

Comment: @meagar as a moderator you should know the button states "This answer is not useful". Disagreeing doesn't make someone's opinion useless

Comment: @Oded wrong! I am not accepting being used for a political purpose. That doesn't mean I cannot tolerate the agenda. Tolerance in the last sentence is more about *you* who cry loud about tolerance, is able to tolerate opinions that against you own

Comment: @K3N As a 55k user you should know that downvotes on meta mean [disagreement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)...

Comment: @K3N Then what is the problem with changing the logo for a couple of days? What is the major issue here that the site owners cannot change the logo to reflect a monumental moment in history? Because that's all that's happened on the site. The logo changed from orange to rainbow, a temporary change, and this post was "featured" most likely to prevent people asking why.

Comment: No one is using you. No one.

Comment: @meagar I see the downvote buttons purely as an emotional button... to be honest

Comment: @Oded when the site/company flag a sosiopolitcal cause giving the impression that "everbody" (ie. users) are on-board, that is abusing its position (regardless if users  are on-board or not).

Comment: @SterlingArcher without the users contribution this company would be nothing

Comment: _"giving the impression that "everbody" (ie. users) are on-board"_ Once again I ask, how is this is any way saying this is everyone's opinion if not everyone can change the logo?

Comment: @K3N Youtube changed it's logo. Google changed its logo. Twitter changed its logo. These are platforms that are used to tout every possible political philosophy imaginable. **Nobody** thinks that "everybody" who uses these services are in it for the politics, or that they support one particular political view. This is just an insane conversation to be having. Toronto flies a pride flag every year. Nobody, anywhere, ever, could possibly think that that means only *one* political opinion exists in a city of 10 million people because they fly a flag for a day or a week. **Please**, drop it.

Comment: @Kendra because SO/SE can and is, using their number of users as "weight" as a corporate/political player. They are seem fragmented per user, but as one unit (company)

Comment: @K3N Once again, if it bothers you that much, leave. If you oppose something a site does, _don't visit that site._ You have the right to just walk away and not be associated. I see zero issue with a site _whose owner is directly affected by this event_ changing a logo's colors for a couple days, but if you do, then you have a right to have a problem with that, but instead of futily complaining, _just walk away._

Comment: You don't have to participate in this site. We have too much negativity as it already is.

Comment: Lets see: "leave", "walk away", "too much negativity", "drop it", "Stack doesn't need your consent for anything". I am glad too so many self-thinking individual who knows exactly what they are talking about, This is just sad..

Comment: I should have worded my last comment better, my apologies: I was more thinking along the lines of, "If you don't like what a company is doing, don't give them your business." Rereading it, it didn't come off that way. But that was what I meant by, "if it bothers you that much, leave." I more meant, "If you don't like what's going on here, don't support it and don't give SE your views, contributions, etc." Very sorry if it came off harshly. :(

Comment: @Kendra no problem Kendra! all good

Comment: "please go away", now THAT is exactly what I meant with "tolerance in practice" :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but these "love it or leave it" comments are pretty unhelpful. It's a weekend logo change; you can still use the site just as you were yesterday. This may affect a lot of Stack Overflow users' personal lives, but is pretty unlikely to actually change how the site works - if you're ok with *that*, you're safe just ignoring *this*.

Comment: I don't see how a rainbow flag on a web site will reflect on you, as one of its millions of users, in any way. As Shog says, you can simply continue using the site as normal.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I thought my post was clear on this. It's not about me as a person, but as an user on a site which portrays as a technical Q&A board for programmers. Which then at a blink of an eye flagging it's true political agenda using *every* user in their pool as ballast for this cause. That I have a problem with. It is not stated in ToS that we might (as users) would be a part of political agendas.

Comment: @Shog9 the site's functionality is fine, great actually. This is not what I have a problem with. This "ambush" change going from a technical board to a political one is what bothers me.

Comment: But that's exactly the thing - we, the users, aren't being made part of a political agenda by this. No one will infer from your being a user on this site that you are affiliated with a specific agenda.

Comment: Apologies for all typos - it's not easy for an non-native English to follow-up a hurd/mob ;) real-time. In particular, this "They are seem fragmented per user" should have been "They are **not** seen as fragmented per user..."

Comment: @Pekka웃 we are actually... as the site flags a political agenda, and exists only due to its users. Its like an union, or a political party. All members are, seen from outside, considered supporter of their agenda, political program etc.. This is also the case with companies such as this (values). Everyone understand that not everybody agrees with everything, but this is more about in the public eye impression. But that wasn't really my point in or of itself. If I was member of such a party, I chose myself to be part of a political agenda. When I signed up here it was for quite other reasons.

Comment: @meagar " Downvotes are not a show of intolerance," And voting to delete? (whoever so did).

Comment: But that's just not the case. Millions of people use Google; no one in their right mind would assume that all their users subscribe to the political views of those running the company. The same applies here (although certainly most of us, including myself, are very happy with today's news.)

Comment: Lemme put it this way, @K3N: politics were off-topic yesterday, and every bit as off-topic today. You don't have to worry about this place turning into Reddit over this.

Comment: "Abusive" really? Get a grip.

Comment: I feel it concerning that almost 70 people upvoted this.

Comment: I think all of the above comments say that no-one believes _all_ Stack Overflow users agree politically on the issue of marriage equality, and that's fine. You are welcome to your views, whatever they are, including the view that suggests you've been forced into agreeing with marriage equality. We disagree with that too. You are welcome to regard me as part of a "mob" for commenting too, if you like! (I don't feel mob-like - no pitchfork or torch `:-(`)

Comment: You are going to leave over this? It's a shame for you, but that decision is entirely yours

Comment: @meagar I don't see the changed logos of google and twitter from here in India though :/ or have they reverted it back to the usually one?

Comment: Take a chill pill dude. It's just a logo. And supporting something that promotes equality isn't a bad thing?

Comment: And I get down voted and lose rep points because my question isn't posed exactly the way some teenager thinks it should be? 

What a bunch of "me too, me too" weenies, trying to look "inclusive" and "tolerant" in their own eyes and those of their tiny circle of adoring "me too" friends. 

All this SCOTUS decision has done is to give all people the permission to beg permission of the state to do something the state has no business being involved in the first place. 

Why not also post a shrine to kittens next time?

Comment: @Kendra, "submit to our pride or GTFO", is it?

Comment: @gldraphael You probably didn't see them because they were only changed locally for the US domains, since afterall it's just a matter of local politics anyway.

Answer (score 28):

Rephrasing one of the standout comments:

The **SO community is international**, so I'm not sure why it should be affected by a decision of an USA court. Maybe it would be more appropriate to do this the International Gay Pride Day?

---

**My words:** From The day I started using this platform,I never had a thought that its a company in USA or wherever.From the day I started using this,i thought that It made all of us flourish, and had Not divided us by these harsh worldly topics.
I am not gona leave or run away from anything, But the touch of partiality(words like nationality etc.) was something that was not expected from this platform atleast

---

**Point is:** We need to keep these social issues as much away as we can from this community, We all are aware of the past; discussing these type of things had brought bitter results, because these may be completely opinion based.

Comment: An entire country just gave its citizens freedom of marriage. I'd say that's cause for celebration.

Comment: **SO community is international**

Comment: Calm your bold down, I would put a lot of money betting that international gay people are still happy over this win.

Comment: The community may be international, but _the company_ is not. It is an American company.

Comment: It's also on the front page of BBC News (as of now at least). You can celebrate something that doesn't directly affect you.

Comment: oops, But from the day i started using this platform,I never had a thought that its a company in USA or wherever.From the daya I started using this, It made all of us flourish, and had Not divided us by  these harsh worldly topics. @Kendra

Comment: @SterlingArcher: To play devil's advocate there, Ireland did the same a few weeks ago, but SO didn't change the logo.

Comment: SO is based in the US. SO is not based in Ireland.

Comment: So, the international community can't celebrate???

Comment: I have given an [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297872/115866) to this.

Comment: Living in Switzerland I went "Yeah, one down, many more to go" ... so it affects me even though I'm not there. With all the horrible global news we hear on a daily basis, this has brightened my day to an extent where I think we should be able to handle a rainbow coloured logo.

Comment: So you got a peek behind the proverbial curtain and found out that Stack Overflow was a thing in a place run by people?

Oh and by the way, that chrome extension that was going around that turned every instance of the word 'cloud' on a page to 'butt'?  

Totes gay agenda.

Comment: Another social issue to rage against http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270032/mentor-all-underrepresented-groups-in-ict-industry

Comment: What about those in the USA who do not celebrate over this decision? Who might be saddened over it?

Comment: As someone who has received down votes for programming questions that are not very good, and has been working harder to make sure my questions are relevant, I am very confused by this. I am constantly reminded on the right bar as I am asking a question, "Is this about programming?" Is this about programming?

Answer (score 22):

Joel is gay. A number of the SE employees are gay. This platform is the direct result of their *years* of blood, sweat, and endless nights. Of course the stupid icon should give a nod to their struggle which is soon coming to an end.

If you have a visceral reaction to a rainbow icon, you should try meeting some of the people that work there :)

Comment: There was probably very little blood involved, though.

Comment: @Jhawins have you *met* [@Zypher](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1171131459/George.JPG)?

Comment: No, but he probably doesn't bleed over servers very often.

Comment: @Jhawins These are the words of a person who never had to assemble a computer in a micro ATX case :)

Comment: only to start a new struggle...namely, being married, that is!

Comment: @MDMarra many SE employees in Ireland are gay too. Did it change the logo when Irish people voted in a `referendum` (not a 5-4 court ruling) for equal rights?

Comment: Nop but I would have been OK with that too

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to go out on a limb and try to express my opinions over the Internet. As a straight Asian-American with no close friends or family members who are gay (though I do know gay people, I define "close" as being sufficiently comfortable and open with someone to be able to regularly discuss sensitive issues like this), I arguably have nothing to add to this conversation. I haven't suffered discrimination for my sexual orientation, and I can barely scratch the legal technicalities of the issue.

And yet, I support gay rights. I say "yet" because I don't think I have any personal evidence or even anecdotal experience to justify my stance (unlike many questions on this site, which can be answered with logical and objective reasoning). To answer the question (for the lurking mods and downvoters), I support the colored logo, but not without reservations. The first major obstacle is the "primarily opinion-based" reason for closure of a question. The issue of gay rights will inevitably spark opinions, which can and will spill forth in a never-ending deluge (remember, friends, that free speech only protects you from the government arresting you for your words, and doesn't protect you from offending others).

This brings up the first paradox (and point of contention): Stack Overflow is structured so that users reward other users' objective correctness (as demonstrated by the "primarily opinion-based" reason for closing a question), yet this issue is inherently divisive: objective correctness (which I believe exists on the side of gay rights) can't and won't be uncovered by users who are entrenched in absolutely opposite positions. In other words, we are using a medium that is designed for exactly the opposite of what is going on right now. If you want a medium that is designed for this discussion, try an in-person conversation where participants try to demonstrate some level of empathy (it's tough). Snips aside, you won't communicate well over the internet, and especially not on this site (oh the irony, I know).

"But Alex, didn't you say you supported gay rights?"

I did say that, but that doesn't mean I automatically disagree with anyone who even smells like they think differently than me. Disparaging, discounting, and mocking others for their opinions is dangerously close to (read: exactly the same as) discrimination. I would love to say that same-sex marriage is an unquestionable right or a fact, but the fact is that this society holds itself up by standards that we have collectively agreed to, and things that are "facts" now may disgust people ten or twenty years from now. Sometimes these standards are cruel, exploitative, and disgusting, and we never know so until significant damage has been done.

In that way, American democracy always seems to fall behind: as the gap widens between a majority and minority, the status quo (which favors the majority, which is why it's the status quo in the first place) is perpetuated until a breaking point is reached; even those who benefit from the status quo see its harm. Then the status quo is reevaluated and shifted. But regardless of where it lies, the status quo cannot continuously shift (it's like a discrete function). The disadvantaged will become more disadvantaged; to everyone who has, even more will be given. But the important thing is that we maintain awareness of the status quo and its effects on not just ourselves but on those around us.

It's funny because I was struggling to finish the paragraph above this one while trying to deal with the second point of contention: that SO is a programming/coding website and isn't meant to or supposed to promote social causes. But there's a little number on my profile that I recently discovered after my hiatus from SO: Impact. The whole site isn't just about getting points; it's about helping people. That's why we close questions, have moderators, and collectively work together to reward thoughtful, informative, thorough, and clear solutions. This is a very liberal view of the purpose of SO, I concede. But if you've ever stumbled upon a perfectly crafted answer or provided one for someone else on this site, you know how it feels to help others. Actually, that's an unfair assumption. You might not know, in which case, here's a quick crash course: helping others feels awesome. And protip #2: there are more ways to help others than helping them fix a bug or understand a programming concept. SO is about people. The colored logo acknowledges the discrimination that a group of people have endured, fought against, and finally defeated.

(When you find that anything written above is misguided, feel free to downvote, flag, comment, ban, or whatever. Though, disclaimer round 2, I'm no expert on this topic and likely will be exposed as a complete idiot if you do so. But I'd rather listen and learn from others than shut them out, no matter which side of the issue they're on.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm in full support of this notion, as a heterosexual, non-religious male. I normally don't butt into these types of politics etc, but a couple of these answers are just disgusting. Calling it hate speech, or throat shoving.

All humans have basic rights, rights that existed long before the foundations of any religion.

> "Judge not lest ye be judged yourself."

Gay marriage is legal now on a federal scale. Federal. Separation of church and state. If a little rainbow logo in support of basic freedom of love is too much, kindly downvote, but don't call it hate speech, or idealistic throat shoving.

Support your fellow humans, people, otherwise, what is humanity worth?

Edit: unintended irony: Even Sterling Malory Archer would be ok with this (see, avatar)

Comment: "What is humanity worth" only what its code is worth, of course!

Comment: "If a little rainbow logo in support of basic freedom of love is too much, kindly downvote" yes very true.  That's what we do for every other feature-request.

Comment: For those for it, this simple, tiny sign of support is *huge*. For those against, well, tomorrow it'll be gone and you can forget it ever happened.

Comment: "Judge not lest ye be judged yourself." - don't forget that "judging" here refers to judging people, not their actions. Judging actions and avoiding or refraining from or pleading/encouraging others against sinful actions is normal and expected of Christians.

Comment: *Gay marriage is legal now on a federal scale. Federal.* Good for you, but we are not from the same country. Look at [the map](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-geo) into Active Users tab. I have nothing against that particular law (if it's good for people, be so), just, it doesn't affect me anyhow, I don't care. I just don't like how narrowed is this *celebration*.

Comment: This judgment relates specifically to the USA. SO/SE is much, **much** bigger than that.

Comment: @Vesper Fighting for same-sex marriage rights and getting married to a same-sex partner is a thoroughly deliberate set of actions.  It's absurd to claim that judging those actions is not a judgement of the person who poured their soul into them.

Answer (score -10):

This may be a place for programming Q&A, but it is also a place of *people*; people are from everywhere, and things happen to them. Sometimes, those things are important enough to change their world and, by definition, our world.

A part of StackExchange has just witnessed something monumental. And it is precisely because it happened to *us* that we should recognize it. Changing the logo temporarily sounds like a great way of showing the world that we are not ignorant about the things happening to and around our members, and of reminding ourselves that we are more than just a forum: we are a community.

Comment: A "community" comes together to agree on issues...This "community" has agreed a long time ago that issues discussed within it be 100% programming based.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu yeah, although not on meta. meta is for questions about the site...

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Here is a quote taken directly from the ['What is Meta'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page: "Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow rather than discussing programming itself."

Answer (score -28):

Yes, because one of the goals of SO is to demonstrate its users' political correctness. And given how this goal is relevant to the other goals of this site (some programming related stuffs). I think SO should change the logo everyday to reflect our support on feminism, anti-racism, LGBT rights and all the other stances US supreme court holds.

Comment: ......... what?

Comment: This must be the end of civilization.

Comment: @TLama That hasn't happened yet? :P

Comment: Uhh, yeah do support feminism etc. But tbh I think this is a major step for the world. Keep the sarcastic tones down.

Comment: @enderland It's a sarcastic answer.

Answer (score -71):

Being a Christian, I must oppose. The primary point is that Stack Overflow **does not care** whether there are gays in the outer world, they care for programming, helping, general goodness. Someone being gay is plainly irrelevant to the community reaction to his actions, questions, answers or comments. Therefore positioning SO as "gay friendly" adds nothing to attitude of SO community to actual homosexual people, but has a serious potential to distract outside community into believing that SO *promotes gay movement* by bearing the six-striped rainbow flag.

tl;dr Please don't.

On a side note:  Asking a question at SO is a privilege, it's granted by SO to those that satisfy several constraints, these are written in the TOS. I have to remind that marriage is also a privilege awarded to those who desire to live happily ever after until Death do them part, and not a right. Not everyone are entitled to be married, as not everyone is entitled to post a question at SO and not get scoffed at due to their question being destructive to the community. So, while I understand the CEO's alignment to show his joy to the latest decision of the Supreme Court, this borders *speaking for everyone* and thus is destructive.

Comment: What does it matter if you are Christian? I get that we are a neutral community but this is still a huge event

Comment: The rights granted by government and the status granted by religion are different things. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: I'm Christian. 21 Century dude.

Comment: As an "actual homosexual person", I have to say that positioning SO/SE as gay friendly has meant **everything** to me. I have felt welcome here and distinctly unwelcome in many other spaces.

Comment: I don't think the point is "gay friendly", it's more about "noting a historical landmark". I would view it the same as honoring war veterans.

Comment: Is the inverse true? Does the lack of rainbow colored flag indicate that we are against the gay movement?

Comment: Of all the arguments against this, comparing marriage rights to the ability to vote on a Q&A web site has got to be the most nonsensical.

Comment: In the world of the internet where everyone is kind of an asshole, it's nice to be able to pursue my passion in an environment that doesn't tolerate discrimination.

Comment: Even Pope Francis said: "Who I am to judge them?" Let the rainbow in!

Comment: I too consider myself a Christian, but I think it's equally as irrelevant to the conversation as Joel stating that he's gay. I think the conversation is about whether or not the SE network should get behind social causes (be it this one or something else) by publicly waving the banner of the cause.

Comment: Being another _devote_ Christian, I see absolutely zero wrong with _the owners and maintainers of the site_ deciding they wish to change one small part of the design for a day or two to show their support for a cause that directly affects them. _"...marriage is also a privilege... and not a right."_ In America, we are supposed to be guaranteed the right to, and I quote, "Life, liberty, and _the pursuit of happiness._" The pursuit of happiness includes marriage, therefore it is a right to get married. _"this borders speaking for everyone and thus is destructive."_ Can everyone change the icon?

Comment: Think of it like this.  Remember the time that Joel came out publicly against GoDaddy?

Comment: `Not everyone are entitled to be married` You are right.  But every heterosexual couple can marry.  doesn't matter if they can have kids or not.

Comment: It's not "gay-friendly", it's "people-friendly"; That's the whole point...

Comment: Given the proportion of people in tech who are openly gay having a place that does not discriminate and has trashed negative comments is _huge_. The point is that Stack Overflow does care. Thankfully.

Comment: As both a Christian and a bi lady, I can see room for celebrating the awesome step towards a lot more people being able to have a little more happiness in their lives in a public way. Knowing SE doesn't care who I love or who I am, just the cool knowledge I can bring to the sites makes me all the happier to hang out and be a part of the awesome.

Comment: @PeterStegnar Speaking of Pope, "judging" really means "condemning for sins", and is indeed prohibited, as only God can judge, as he knows everything. I don't judge people, but I can judge people's actions. This proposed action is IMO destructive.

Comment: _"This proposed action is IMO destructive"_ How is this action destructive? How is painting _an image on a website that takes up next to no space on your screen_ destructive? I could see that argument, or your "speaking for everyone" argument if _anyone_ could go in and change that logo, but only those who run this site can. They are speaking for them, not for everyone.

Comment: Please don't compare Stack Overflow's standards of quality to the *government* telling consenting adults what they can and cannot do.  This is the kind of ridiculous thinking that leads people to scream "but my freedom of speech! I thought this was America" when they get asked to keep their voices down in a movie theatre. A private corporation telling you how to use *their* website or property is not the same as the government imposing restrictions on freedom.

Comment: Just read what Jesus had to say about divorce, and then see if the goverment's allowance of divorce jives with your Chirstian values.

Comment: "*Being a Christian, I must oppose*" - I strongly disagree with the implication that being a Christian mandates one's position on this subject.

Comment: "Not everyone are entitled to be married" this is why we can't have nice things

Comment: Don't you just hate when a Christian has to declare their Christianity to prove they're a Christian? What about that old song, *"They will know we are Christian by our love..."*?

Comment: If "Stack Overflow does not care whether there are gays in the outer world", then why should it care that you're Christian either?

Comment: Everyone. Stop commenting. Move on. Those who matter don't mind and those who mind don't matter.

Comment: On that note, do we have a hate speech flag? Because this literally falls under hate speech.

Comment: @Jhawins Although I don't see the "hate speech" part of it, it would fall under "rude and abusive." I fully expect any flag of that nature on this answer to be declined. As multiple mods and team members (I think just team members) have commented here already, if they saw something bad in this answer, they would have deleted it already.

Comment: "this borders speaking for everyone and thus is destructive." - well, Stack Overflow is a community driven _private company_, it's speaking for the people running this site and also the community that agrees with them. If you disagree with our community consensus you may - but expect this to be against you should you ever choose to seek any position in the site.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum they do that in public companies too.  Who do you complain to when your companies newsletter features gay adoptive parents?

Comment: The rainbow flag represents people of all kinds, including Christians. This is not about gays, this is about celebrating equality among developers. I'm a bit sad if people don't want to join us for religious reasons -- there's space for everyone, even people I don't agree with, like the OP.

Comment: @PeterTurner I wouldn't complain to anyone. I see nothing wrong with same-sex parents. In fact I find the notion I get to tell other people how to live their lives offensive, and thus when companies showcase support for personal and interpersonal freedom I'm generally in favour. Sadly, we're not as progressive as a country and gay marriage isn't legal here yet.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum "Everything you say might be used against you"? Let them. Sadly as it may be, I don't have enough time to devote to SO to ever apply for a position in the company. Also "consensus" is a slippery word here, first, meta isn't as representative of the entire SO community (even if dropping those 61% that asked a question and left), and second, as you've just said, mods are chosen for loyalty as well as other factors and they have little choice but to pipe in the CEO's voice.

Comment: @Vesper Stack Overflow community elects the mods. We don't pick them.

Comment: @Sklivvz There's some trickery under the hood of using this flag as a symbol of everyone. It might be that I'm misinformed, and LGBT movement does mean "everyone has the right to be happy" with it - okay, it's just *too* associated with that movement to think about other possible meanings of the rainbow. There's a word here in Russia, related to the flag, "Leave the rainbow to children" - and this position has some serious ground.

Comment: @AnnaLear I have watched the election process, and yes this is true. What is not known, however, how is it determined who stays and who doesn't. I may be wrong here, though, but I have met companies where piping a voice against the Big Boss means imminent firing of that person. And if ever some team member receives money from the StackExchange company, they will be bound to not misbehave if such things are in place.

Comment: @Vesper What do you mean by "who stays and who doesn't"? Folks resign sometimes, but beyond that, they serve indefinitely. Our policies (including activity) are out in the open on meta and in the election descriptions. (And moderators don't get paid.)

Comment: @Vesper There is a well defined [process in place for removing a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/186381).  There is also a [moderator agreement](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) that they need to follow.  There is no clause at all prohibiting speaking out against the company in SE's policy.  Mods are also volunteers, not employees.

Comment: @AnnaLear Okay, this is not in effect then. Good.

Comment: @Vesper the LGBT movement's aim is to promote equality with respect to sexual orientation. Their symbol stands for equality. Our company promotes equality among developers (including equality with respect to sexual orientation). Do you see a parallel there?

Comment: Tell you what, when Christian turns into a marginalized group that's stripped of its rights, and it then manages to get some rights back, they'll put a cross in the logo.

Now can someone help me calculate the odds of that timeline actually happening in a time considered short by mammals?

Comment: @Matt And what does it matter if you are gay? You don't care about if somebody a christian, ok, I don't care if someone is gay so don't force their propaganda on me.

Comment: @jadarnel27 If you read and beleive the whole Bible, what basically makes someone a christian, [then according to it](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/177/3913) you have to oppose it.

Comment: Another dictate that makes me very thankful that I am an Atheist.

Comment: I disagree with the logo being there for reasons, mostly because I think Stack should be neutral in such things. However I'm not against what it stands for as we all should be willing to accept each other's opinions and views. Many Gay folks will be happy for you to have your beliefs, and part of being a Christian is "love thy neighbour" and forgiving people even if their beliefs are not yours. I'm not a Christian, but let me say this: God being against Gays was the OLD Testament and God has moved on, learned his lesson, as can be seen in the New Testament. Why can't his followers do the same?

Comment: @totymedli the bible also promotes slavery, prohibits the consumption of bacon, and does not permit women to speak in church. Are you going to try to enforce or re-live all of those things too? Go with something more simple: **live and let live**. If my sister-in-law marries her girlfriend, why is that something you need to oppose? How on earth does it negatively affect you?

Comment: @AaronBertrand It doesn't promote slavery nor womens speak in church you can't take passages out of context and also you have to understand where it uses tropology. The prohibiton of bacon consumption basically aplies to jews and in the old testament because new testament clarifies that Jesus's blood washes it. And I don't care about what your sister-in-law does, they allowed to do immoral things and I still respect them as human beings even if I don't agree with them, but I raise my voce if they want to declare their unnatural relationship in the same level as a healthy marriage.

Comment: @totymedli I find it amusing how people take certain portions of the bible and demand that everyone live by them and if they don't they're a sinner. But it's only the parts of the bible that are convenient for them to treat that way - if any other parts are brought up, they're waved away as "out of context." Thump elsewhere.

Comment: when this rainbow will disappear? it's very irritating.

Comment: @Alex So is not being allowed to marry the person you love...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Where did I forced or even told you to live according to the Bible? We were talking about christians and they living according to the Bible. Shouldn't that be the way? I didn't take out only the convenient parts, I didn't waved away anything or said it was "out of context". I answered to your arguments which were misinterpretations of the Bible thus I explained why your arguments are invalid but I had to done this in a short way because an exhaustive explanation would be waaaay longer than what this 500 character textbox allows for me.

Comment: @totymedli First you said "if you read and believe the whole Bible" and now you're saying only the parts you agree with are relevant. So which is it? If you can say that some parts of the Bible are important and others aren't, why do you get to pick which ones Christians should live by and which can be ignored?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Where did I said that only the parts you agree are relevant? My whole last comment was about not taking out parts from the Bible...

Comment: I wish I could give a p1us one million on this one. God bless you @Vesper

Comment: Being a Christian absolutely mandates your opinion on the subject, unless you disregard the Bible, which'd be funny.

Comment: @Ilia this is why the Bible sucks, because obeying this part means you must ignore other parts (like unconditionally loving thy neighbor), and let's not forget about all the other parts you conveniently pretend don't exist.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The main trouble is that one has to comply with both loving his neighbor and hating his sins. It's doable, but with great strain on the believer.

Comment: @Vesper if your neighbor isn't a Christian and doesn't follow the Bible, they're not sinning. So your hatred is misplaced.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, actions against the Ten Commandments are still sins, although the neighbor might be unaware of his actions being sinful. (It's hard to be unaware these days, such person just decides to not follow the Bible or the TC, which is considered a sin as well, but our actions should not be to humiliate a sinner, but to explain why is it so and finally leave them be - "you want to live in sin, it's your right, but then don't complain if God would say 'why did you not adhere to that guy?'")

Comment: @Vesper News flash: Not everyone in the world is Christian, never mind Catholic, and not everyone believes in any God, never mind your God. P.S. What Bible are all the pedophile Catholic priests following?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am aware of this, but still, there are but a few communities that have never heard the Bible in some form. P.S.: The pedophile Catholic priests follow the same Bible, but commit sins. The power perverts people, and priests have a lot of power. It's like a monarch that reigns supreme and does evil things in the backyard thinking no one would know. Sad but true.

Comment: @Vesper I've heard of ISIS and Al Qaeda and the Quran as well. Should I start listening to all of these, including your Bible, through osmosis? Who are you to tell anyone that your Bible is right and theirs is wrong? Use your Bible to judge your own actions, not the actions of others. If the Bible hasn't taught you that much, you're a lost cause.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, there are at least [Eucharistic miracles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharistic_miracle) available to have a say for my side being the right one. The last time I queried, there were 126 of these, the last to my knowledge occurred in [2008](http://www.catholic.org/news/international/europe/story.php?id=43101) (investigation in progress). About listening to everyone - sure do, but analyze not just words, but also actions.

Comment: @Vesper Sorry, the fact that you believe in miracles does not make your Bible "the right" Bible. /unsubscribe

Comment: @Vesper I'm all for SO staying neutral but you don't help the cause by sounding like a raving nut-case *(no offence)*.