# Had the community responded in a negative way towards changing the site's logo temporarily, would Stack Overflow have changed it regardless?

Tags: discussion, meta

A request to change the site's logo was posted in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow) question and was soon accepted. The Stack Overflow logo was changed for this weekend.

Looking at the votes alone, the community was in agreement with the temporary change. Had the community reacted differently and was against the change (eg. 400 downvotes on the question), would Stack Overflow have applied the change regardless?

Comment: Oh, hell.  This has already happened.  I can lock the original question now, free of any WASPy guilt.

Comment: Also, I'm voting to close your question as hypothetical.  I left my magic 8 ball at home this morning.

Comment: Yes,  it would have been done anyway.  Co-founder and inventor of StackOverflow posted in the original thread and shared his thoughts.

Comment: I don't know what we would've done with a score of -400 (burn the site down?), but we had essentially decided that the legislative milestone was important to us as people and as a company enough that we would change the logo. The community support was really heartening to see, but we would not have avoided the change for fear of backlash.

Comment: @AnnaLear That's what I wanted to hear. Respect.

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh no, don't call action by the Supreme Court a "legislative milestone"; that's sure to get them riled!

Comment: Interestingly, it does have 150 downvotes :P