# Can I turn off the rainbow version of the logo?

Tags: feature-request, logo

I mean, I understand this tolerance thing, but can I at least choose whether I'm in favor of the new social logo or not ([Please do not use Stack Overflow to promote social causes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes)) and change it back to normal in case I'm not?

**EDIT**
I have created another feature request which addresses the future questionable changes like this one, here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297988/can-i-opt-out-any-minor-site-changes-reflecting-some-social-or-political-events

Comment: @psubsee2003 could you please point me if there was something about an option to change logo back, for example, in profile settings?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@santiago Stack Overflow is (supposed to be) a programming Q&A site, where professionals hang out. Not really the best place to promote social causes, especially causes that have absolutely nothing to do with programming. This isn't Facebook.

Comment: Well, @Yannis you are a mod, so you must be right.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@santiago Thanks, I somehow managed to miss that discussion. I strongly disagree with Joel there, I'm in the "do not promote any social causes ever" camp. Even for causes that I strongly support, like this one.

Comment: @AskarKalykov exactly why I removed my duplicate vote.  After 2nd read I realized this was a feature request to turn it off.  At best my duplicate is related.

Comment: A (professional?) programmer would not ask this question. (S)he would write a user script that hide/change the logo. Problem solved.

Comment: Because Joel told , he is gay and want to promote social issue against gays , please refer here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå already done [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3627546#3627546), problem solved indeed, discussion closed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 my bad, I was totally knocked out with these news and haven't managed to organize my question in the right way.

Comment: Anyway, regarding to the logo change, I somewhat satisfied with the idea that the change itself was a personal (biased) decision of Joel, thus community's attitude here is ignored (although his answer has maximum upvote counter, I see that decision is not so obvious for the community).

Comment: GreaseMonkey solution: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297978/an-url-for-svg-asset-file-with-old-banner-colors, incomplete because of lack of proper svg resource.

Comment: @AskarKalykov: also, the community voted, and it was much more in favour of the logo change than not ([currently 563 in favour to 150 against](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297859/472495)).

Comment: @halfer, still, I think this little change with the subsequent discussion upset more people than make happy ([for example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297878/960757)). I'm in the *"do not promote any social causes ever"* camp (and I agree with [this reaction](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297931/960757)).

Comment: @halfer more than 1 in 5 answers is against the change, you can't just drop them off the equation. I think that it would be obvious for SE to give people chance to choose if they want to see the logo in their version of the site.

Comment: Obviously provocative and potentially offensive headings as [in the original version of this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/297974/1) do not help your viewpoint either.

Comment: If you are actually interested in genuine responses rather than just trolling (which I doubt): Since the logo is probably going to change back in a few days, I really don't think its worth development time to add an option.

Comment: @santiago that was my first impression, and I had already got the idea after looking on to downvote counter. Thought people could get sarcastic notes though.

Comment: @Askar: you've identified a flaw in democracy called "[the tyranny of the majority](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tyranny+of+the+majority)" (though one could argue that we're celebrating the end of another tyranny of the majority!). On binary questions, how do you propose to resolve this? If 5:1 are in favour of something, then we should _not_ do it?

Comment: ..or @AskarKalykov do you expect to do what you want, just because you demand it?

Comment: @TLama: it would be very sad indeed if someone threw away a 50K account, and all the goodwill it represents, over such a trivial issue. I presume the SC decision doesn't affect that individual, so they should just ignore it.

Comment: @TZHX Ok I now think of an option to abstract the feature request and ask for the possibility to rollback ANY further social/political/other logo/colors changes. As said many times before, SO is a professional site after all.

Comment: @santiago well, the situation here is clear: if a question is about minor change, let people enable the change in their profiles

Comment: @halfer, that was just one high-rep example. You may find more of them in the thread. The losses are higher than benefit, I'd say. And it was not about that SC decision, but about the principle of this site.

Comment: @halfer one just can not force people being "polite", because on the international resource you deal with different social and political systems, and democracy is only one of them.

Comment: @AskarKalykov it is clear now, and is reasonable now.

Comment: @Yannis _Not Programming Related_, rings a bell? :)

Comment: @santiago to be clear, I'll try to put my thoughts together - why this exact situation looks weird to me. Why the logo reflecting us court outcome is there? If it's personal decision of Joel then OK (a). If it's the decision of the community, then why only US? If it's not only about US, then should SO reflect same court wins in other countries? by the way, which (b)? Otherwise - in case if it's only about US, then to hell with internationalization (c). --> So what is it - a, b, or c? If b - should we wait for "social spam" on SO?

Comment: @AskarKalykov, like I said `it is clear now, and is reasonable now`

Comment: The CEO and Co-Founder of this site is gay, if you have a problem, you probably shouldn't be here.

Comment: @MarcusJ No one complains about the CEO being gay. He agrees that the site shouldn't be used to promote social causes, but makes an exception for himself - that's what people are complaining about. Of course, he has the right to do it, as others have the right to be unhappy about it.

Comment: @Malcolm you completely misinterpret why Joel is showing support through StackOverflow.

Comment: @Qix Just saying "you are wrong" without explaining why is rather unhelpful.

Comment: @Malcolm because I am physically fatigued trying to explain something to nay-sayers who are incapable of doing the slightest bit of research on their own.

Comment: @Qix If you refer to the Joel's post, I've definitely seen it, that's exactly why I wrote my comment.

Comment: @Malcolm Joel's post isn't the only bit of research you need to do on gay marriage.

Comment: @Qix Then I don't see your point because I'm only discussing Joel's decision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81756/discussion-between-malcolm-and-qix).

Comment: I had a better opinion about stackoverflow. I think it's not appropriate when people promote their views through site like this. Before that I thought this site for programmers, engineers etc for people for whom not important religion or sexual orientation. Hope wikipedia and other popular will not to do things like this, it's not appropriate for open community imho.

Comment: Completely disgusting behaviour by SO to promote their views like this. This should be a site for purely technical activity related to software engineering.

Comment: it seems that answer to your question is no. The whole situation is very unprofessional and quite dissapointing.

Answer (score 32):

The owners and operators of Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have made it amply clear that while we as users and contributors are not permitted to use the site and our audience here to promote our political and social beliefs, they, as the owners may.

See the accepted answer here:
[Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed temporarily to the "#LoveOverflows" logo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1)

It is clearly now policy that they as owners of Stack Exchange can and will use the goodwill and site traffic generated by our contributions to promote any political or social cause they see fit.

If you do not like this you should no longer contribute to Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is called bias and subjectivity. We shouldn't forget theme of the site "The world’s largest programming community"

Comment: "If you do not like this you should no longer contribute to Stack Exchange."....heartache :'(

Comment: You can use your profile to advance your political and social beliefs just fine, as long as you do not attack any individual or group. That's been the case for years, so if you've got a cause to advance, put it there. It extends to avatars too, I think.

Comment: "If you do not like this you should no longer contribute to Stack Exchange." - Unfortunately there are no good alternatives to this site, so we don't have much of a choice left.

Comment: "If you do not like this you should no longer contribute to Stack Exchange" I agree with that, though it saddens me and would be a net-loss for everyone. A lot of people want to celebrate the gay-rights as big win that's bringing people together, but at the same time it can help promote a schism in the community. That's why I believe SO should remain apolitical on all topics unless they directly related to the site.

Comment: Isn't this hyprocrisy? We as users are not allowed to promote any political or social cause but the owners can? Afterall, it's the users which have made this site what it is, not the owners.

Comment: Personally, I have difficulty enough avoiding stepping on toes on this issue, whether this be at home, in social networks, at work, on in the number of volunteer positions I work with.

I find it unfortunate that the one community which was completely free of social clap-trap is now shouting at me.

Comment: "If you do not like this you should no longer contribute to Stack Exchange"

I have more benefits to use SO and help it be better than try to find an alternative.

Comment: just cut all that crap about importance

Comment: @cwallenpoole "Shouting" at you seems a bit strong of a description. It's not like they made the logo bigger, or blinky, or anything.

Comment: @ObliviousSage No, they just put it in the spot you are most likely to see it on every page load.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I didn't even notice the change until I saw the huge stink a few people were raising about it in Meta. When I load a page on SO the thing I am mostly like to see is the **actual content of the page**. Short of nothing, changing the icon's color for a couple days is *literally* the least they could do. I can understand feeling strongly about the court's decision, and I can understand not liking that SO changed their icon. I just don't get how you got from being passionately opposed to *gay marriage* to being passionately opposed to a particular *color scheme* for a website icon.

Comment: @ObliviousSage, the notion of a "gay marriage" and the colour scheme is linked. Are you suggesting there is no link?

Comment: "It is clearly now policy that they as owners of Stack Exchange can and will use the goodwill and site traffic generated by our contributions to promote any political or social cause they see fit." - **THIS IS ABUSE OF POWER.** - I never signed up for this when I joined SO.

Comment: @I.K. Of course there's a link. But there's also a difference in scale. Again, I can absolutely understand people being upset about the court ruling. It's a topic that lot of people have very strong feelings about on both sides. What I *don't* understand is having very strong feelings about one website expressing an opinion about the ruling in the most subdued way possible. I can feel strongly about gay marriage without throwing an enormous hissy fit when someone else quietly states an opinion about gay marriage that is contrary to my own.

Comment: @I.K. Abuse of power? It's a *privately-owned website*. If you feel that a slight change to the site's icon is more important than the benefit the site provides to you, then stop using it. That seems kind of extreme to me, though. Google changed their icon, will you stop using their services? I believe Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, and plenty of others changed their icons as well, are you going to stop using those services?

Comment: @ObliviousSage, it may be a privately owned website but this site would have been nothing if it wasn't for the software engineers who have posted their answers and questions over time. Surely we should have more of a say in this matter than is being suggested by you and Ben. The main argument is that this is a site for purely technical matters related to software engineering and not LGBT agendas. And with regards to voting on the matter, I never even saw that.

Comment: @I.K. Are you suggesting that you missed the voting (perfectly understandable, I did too) or that you don't think there *was* voting (because there totally was, until the question got locked due to flame wars)? The best analogy for this angriness I can think of is that someone at work you've interacted with a number of times before casually mentioned they agree with the court case and you're denouncing them as evil and refusing to work with them ever again. You have an opinion, SO has an opinion. SO happened to state theirs in a place you can see. It's not like they donated money or anything.

Comment: @Oblivious Sage your analogy is completely off track. I stated the main argument in my previous comment. Read it again.

Comment: @I.K. It's a privately-owned website. They usually try to get user input. In this case they *did* get user input, the majority of which was supportive (changing the icon was in fact *suggested* by users). But they're not *required* to get user input. If you feel that you can't support what they're doing with the site, then you're welcome to stop patronizing it. I feel like that would be a huge overreaction to something that has pretty much zero impact, though (the icon change, not the court case).

Comment: @Oblivious promoting social and political views is not zero impact.

Comment: @I.K. If they had asked you to do something (like the giant banner they put at the top of every page when they were promoting opposition to SOPA/PIPA), that would be promotion. If they had put it up *before* the court case was decided, that would be promotion. But they did neither of those things. All they did was congratulate the winning side.

Comment: @ObliviousSage, your points are mute. What if I put up the Confederate flag after the massacre in Charleston?

Comment: @I.K. You would be expressing your opinion (entirely your right), not promoting racism/slaughter. If you went around telling people they should kill black people, *that* would be promotion.

Comment: @ObliviousSage, you are desperately trying to back up your weak argument now. Normal people don't think how you are describing. There is symbolism. People look at a symbols and derive the most *obvious* meaning from it. In this case, support of LGBT agenda which has nothing to do with SO really.

Comment: @I.K. My point is that you can *support* something without *promoting* it. The Confederate flag is a bit of a red herring since it symbolizes different things to different people. If SO had changed their logo to a frowny face or something for the weekend to display unhappiness with the gay marriage ruling, I wouldn't have ranted in Meta about it, demanding they never take sides in issues or threatening to leave the site, I would have shrugged and moved on. After all, it's not like they're actually giving money to support either side.

Comment: @ObliviousSage, I'm not sure how much more clearer I can make it for you. The LGBT agenda or any other social or political agenda has no place on SO whether a person is for those issues or against them. The site should be free of all that crap. Do you get it now?

Comment: @I.K. I understand feeling that way. What I don't understand is how **strongly** people seem to feel about it. Yet again, I haven't seen anyone explain how SO changing its logo for a couple days has any *significant* impact on them. There's a ton of stuff on SO that isn't relevant to me. I just *ignore* it.

Comment: @ObliviousSage, because social and political issues have a *HUGE* impact. Wars have been started over that crap... It's not something to take lightly.

Comment: @I.K. Again, the issues *themselves* have a huge impact. SO changing its logo does *not*. Are you seriously suggesting that SO changing their logo caused even a single person to change their mind about gay marriage?

Comment: @ObliviousSage, we are going around in circles here because you forget the points I make in my previous comments. End of conversation.

Answer (score 17):

If you use Greasemonkey for Firefox (alternatives for other browsers exist), use the following userscript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('hlogo');
el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
```

It removes the "stackoverflow" text, but it's still better than to look at their propaganda.

Comment: Clever. Can you also create a userscript that hides answers from certain users? So I don't have to look at their propaganda.

Answer (score 16):

YES, just use this customized CSS inside your browser (or use some proxy, or alter the data with some packet based fiter). [Guide for firefox](https://ffeathers.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/how-to-override-css-stylesheets-in-firefox/), [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en), [safari extension](http://code.grid.in.th/).

```
#hlogo a { background-position: -32px 0px !important; }
```

And you'll see this.

[image: after change]

Much better now.

Comment: Now THIS is the kind of response I expect from Stack Overflow users. Kudos for finally implementing a technical solution, the *best kind* of solution!

Comment: @Shog9 I'd argue that this is one of those wonderful class of issues that Garrett Hardin (in the opening paragraphs of *Tragedy of the Commons*) called "no technical solution problems". No amount of code is going to is going to solve a people problem. All respect to user423948123 for the attempt, but he might as well try to get to Mars in a car.

Comment: The latter portion of my comment may have been slightly facetious, @damien

Comment: @DamienH the "to mars in a car" thing sounds way more plausible 5 years later, apparently

Answer (score 9):

If you are in the "do not promote any social causes ever" camp (which I don't consider an unreasonable position), how does hiding the promotion *from yourself alone* help your cause?

What such a feature would provide would be the ability to make your own filter bubble a bit smaller by not realising when the site is promoting some social cause or whatever. That's not something you would want in the "do not promote any social causes ever" camp. That's something you would want in the "just leave me out of it" camp.

You're free to create your own experience of Stack Overflow, but if you are in the "do not promote any social causes ever" camp, please do yourself and your peers in the same camp a favour and don't just try to pretend that Stack Overflow is not promoting any social causes ever.

Comment: Because for some of us we simply *don't care and don't want to*.

Comment: I'm in the "let me use site for programming and not to get involved in some local events of questionable importance" camp.

Comment: @AskarKalykov Yes, changing the color of their logo certainly *involved* you in the events in question... (*rolls eyes*)

Comment: "You may not be interested in war, but war is interested in you."

Answer (score 6):

You can just wait and it will be changed back later this week (as answered here) ->

[When are we going to get the old logo back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298119/504873)

P.S. I liked Stack Overflow more when it was just about programming. Regardless of which side of the fence you fall on this subject it sucks to have anything that splits the Stack Overflow community :(. There's so much we can do together!!!

Comment: I think that site owners got the feedback and would take it into account when they go for another site-wide campaign.