# A URL for SVG asset file with old banner colors

Tags: support, logo

I wrote a small Greasemonkey script to replace the new rainbow banner:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LoveOverflows
// @namespace   User
// @description Removes StackOverflow rainbow banner
// @include     *.stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle (" \
    #hlogo a { \
        background-image: url('http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/sprites.svg?v=46c88edf8d39') !important; \
    } \
");
```

I used Meta Stack Overflow banner URL here, because apparently [SVG file with image assets for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg) was replaced and I could not find a URL for SVG with the old colors.

Can someone provide me with URL to such a resource?

Comment: a related feature request is [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297974/can-i-turn-off-the-rainbow-version-of-the-logo). Your post could have been an answer there.

Comment: @rene, this solution is incomplete without proper image file, that's why I'm asking. I expect that there is a backup copy of old logo somewhere that could be hosted along with a new one.

Comment: I believe that is solved [here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3627546#3627546)

Comment: @rene, that's exactly what I asked about, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: It is not mine and I don't want to bother @Undo. You can always self answer with proper attribution.

Answer (score 2):

The URL was posted [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3627546#3627546), so the script becomes:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LoveOverflows
// @namespace   User
// @description Removes Stack Overflow rainbow banner
// @include     *stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle (" \
    #hlogo a { \
        background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=46c88edf8d39') !important; \
    } \
");
```

It was provided by [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) in the comment section.

Comment: The url was posted by [Undo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo)