# Make the rainbow logo a hyperlink to the explanation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, logo

I was unpleasantly surprised to see the subject, because I wondered if SE has started to promote LGBT, or *adopted it as an official practice for its employees or something.* Only after searching for a while did I discover it was celebrating a ruling by the US Supreme court and it is supposed to only be there for a couple of days.

Though I'm in the ["no controversial social cause promotions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297974/can-i-turn-off-the-rainbow-version-of-the-logo#comment212708_297974) camp, if the site's owners really can't live without this, I'm hereby asking to make the logo a hyperlink [to the relevant discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow) (like [Google does](https://www.google.com/doodles/about), for example) so everyone knows what this is all about.

Not everyone lives in the US or follows the news.

Comment: I would rather wish the site remained neutral. There are plenty issues in the world that need attention, but out of all of them gay marriage in US is picked. I am very disappointed to see this.

Comment: @Malcolm that's why I said "if site owners really can't live without this". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297974/can-i-turn-off-the-rainbow-version-of-the-logo shows clearly they aren't going to "remain neutral" or remove it.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I'm totally with you, the site owners are clearly very biased. There are much more serious problems in the world than what US says about gay marriage, but this site is the wrong place to deal with them nontheless.

Comment: Ehh, the decision has been made. And no, a site's logo should go to the homepage. Google *can* link elsewhere because you're already on the homepage.

Comment: @Tim, I'm asking to only make *the logo* a hyperlink. The "stackoverflow" text next to it shall still lead to the home page.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it's one thing, not 2 seperate images.

Comment: @Tim, Though it's not too much work to make them separate, this indeed doesn't make sense in the long run (unless you're planning to promote things on a regular basis ;-)). Then there are alternative ways: for example, add a transparent `<div>` overlaying a part of the image.

Comment: @Malcom, "very biased" is a little presumptuous don't you think? Also, while it is a website and therefore has "international" users, the last time I checked StackExchange was located [in the US](https://www.google.com/search?q=Where+is+StackExchange+located&oq=Where+is+StackExchange+located&aqs=chrome..69i57.10526j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @Don'tWasteYourTime let's not go off on a tangent, shall we? In brief, your nickname.

Comment: Having the image link to one place and the text link to another is horrible UX. Besides, you already found the discussion, can't you just bookmark it if you want to read it again?

Comment: *"adopted it as an official practice for its employees"* - yes, that's right, all SE employees must now be gay-married, even (and perhaps especially) if they're straight.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there are people with all kind of crazes out there, anything could be :-) On a serious note, I imagined this as encouraging making out in public and such.

Comment: @jonrsharpe besides, after your edit, the phrase looks like I was completely serious - while back in italics, it hinted I was actually making a wild guess.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The explanation is linked to in the sidebar of pretty much *every page on the site*.

[image]

If you can't find it, oh well - this'll be done in two more days, and isn't worth screwing with the navigation for that time.

If we ever do this again, maybe we take the time to put a subheading on it or something.

#### See also: [What should clicking on the Site Logo & "Questions" links in the site header do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259278/what-should-clicking-on-the-site-logo-questions-links-in-the-site-header-do)

Comment: I have proposed a way to do this without screwing the navigation.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it is a weekend for goodness sakes, and the logo will be back to normal on Monday - so you basically want someone to give up their weekend to change this for something that will not be see in 24 more hours?

Comment: No, I don't. Since no one brought up 29.06 (only "a couple of days") or your work schedule for me to be able to make any assessments regarding them. (The discussion does have Tim mention a "weekend" - in a deep-buried comment which, as such, is in no way an authoritative source)

Comment: If the proposed change *is* troublesome to make, and the campaign will be over by tomorrow, there really is little meaning for it.