# Can Stack Overflow's logo be changed permanently to a spectral colours logo?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, logo

## TL;DR

Please change the SO logo permanently to the one below showing stack objects in spectral colours. The old orange (orange? [Ubuntu](http://design.ubuntu.com/) anyone?) one doesn't properly reflect the diversity of programming-related content on SO, or the diversity of its user base for that matter. A logo with spectral colours does. Also, change the hover pop-up to reflect the same.

## Request proper

### Background

Inspired by a recent [popular discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow) here on meta, I'd like to propose a permanent change of logo to the one depicted below.

While its original implementation can be - and has been - widely disputed (cf. discussion under the link above as well as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297974/can-i-turn-off-the-rainbow-version-of-the-logo), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298025/make-the-rainbow-logo-a-hypelink-to-the-explanation), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297964/may-i-know-why-logo-was-changed-and-till-when-it-will-be-colorful), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298004/remember-when-you-promised-not-to-imply-that-i-support-your-political-message), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297988/can-i-opt-out-any-minor-site-changes-reflecting-some-social-or-political-events)), there have also been some (or at least [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow#comment211978_297871)) voices of reason amongst the noise, acknowledging the fact that the old - mainly orange - logo could well need an update.

While I, you and s/he may or may not be in favour of the [motivation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297859/731040) for the original change, the question whether it's okay to use the logo to support a non-programming-related cause on SO is a valid one.

However, this request is not about discussing the latter at all. Instead, it's meant to be an example of dialectic [synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis,_antithesis,_synthesis): Solving the conflict between thesis and anthithesis, *creating something better*.

### Motivation and request

Stack Overflow is welcoming ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)) all Qs and As, as long as they are programming-related. However, the same Qs and As in reality differ extremely in terms of

- programming language in question
- level of abstraction
- level of experience of askers and answerers (like, me vs Jon Skeet? Oh boy.)
- etc. etc.

In order to acknowledge this diversity and at the same time acknowledge the fact that Q&A on *all* programming languages, levels of abstraction, levels of experience, etc. etc. are *equally* welcome, I think it'd be all too logical to reflect it in the logo. The logo depicted below does this in that it

1. includes a wide spectrum of colours (diversity)
2. which are all in the same stack at the same time (equality)*.

In other words: The Stack Overflow logo would reflect the site's quality of being the one-stop shop for *all* programming-related Q&A - whether you're a pro [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) coder or a newbie [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) hack, or both at the same time - if it was changed permanently to the below one (properly re-designed if necessary?!?).

### Sidenote: The hover pop-up

Yea, there's that. Change it (back?) to something? I'm not good at taglines, but here's one for want of the real deal: **"Where everything programming-related is equal in all its diversity..."**

### EDIT: On colour schemes

As mentioned above, and in the light of comments and answers: This is meant to be an exercise in synthesis, not a masked political ploy. I think the spectral colours make for a well-balanced colour scheme, [as have others before me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag#Rainbow_flags_in_various_cultures_and_movements). However, I'd be happy with any other more diverse scheme than the orange one.

[image: A version of the SO logo with the stack objects in colours similar to pure [spectral colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_color#Table_of_spectral_or_near-spectral_colors).]

*Well, they are in there one on top of the other, or rather one after another (hey, it's a [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack)), but that also reflects the fact that questions and answers *do* come here one after another.

Comment: I prefer the colours for no other reason than I prefer the colours. Someone else probably won't. Then there's branding, trademarks. Cost-benefit Analysis already done?

Comment: Personally, I prefer the more colorful logo regardless of any underlying message.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Good point. And very pragmatic.

Comment: If this was the original proposal for the logo change (specifically representing diversity) then I might agree. But this logo change is specifically for one purpose (the pro-gay rights agenda) and by no means does that adequately represent the diversity of the site. Are we going to add a Star of David, a cross, a crescent and star etc etc etc in an attempt to represent diversity too? Of course not. It represents what has happened regarding gay rights and no attempt to alter its definition in a way such as this will change that. The sooner we can get back to programming the better.

Comment: @user1672694: I'd be more than happy to accept a different colour scheme. The main spectral colours are an obvious choice however, cf. [Wikipedia on the Rainbow flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag) for example.

Comment: I like it, it reminds me of the [Commodore 64 logo](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140907072807/logopedia/images/2/2c/Commodore_64_logo.png)

Comment: @samgak It's also reminiscent of [Apple's original logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N4wXT.jpg).

Comment: This LGBT stuff is crazy. They literally want to repaint the whole world in rainbow colors, because wherever you go and see no LGBT flags, that place must hate them. If you don't praise their equality/diversity slogan in 24/7 you automatically become a homophobe. The only thing they are persecuted by is their own maniac fanaticism.

Answer (score 19):

...No.

It's good to call attention to it for a weekend, but this is only for a short time.  Stack Overflow's got its color motif, and this really was a spur-of-the-moment change to celebrate a historical Supreme Court ruling.

There's plenty of reason to celebrate the diversity, but I don't see it sticking around permanently.

Comment: See what you mean, edited to clarify.

Comment: I don't know if this has been mentioned yet, but it needs to go because it's missing a color... according to my screen Indigo didn't make the team.

Comment: @slugster: It does, but as far as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_flag) knows, the LGBT version is a modern 6-band one ;).

Answer (score -27):

Very bad idea. **A not-so-clever excuse to mask a political agenda.** Just a coincidence that this came up now? We have an intelligent membership here - I don't believe many of us are as naive as you make us out to be - a bit insulting, I'd say.

In addition, the "diversity" on this site includes Muslims and Christians from all over the world, who are by no means celebrating Friday's decision, so your attempt at demonstrating "diversity" is actually exclusionary, as is SO's temporary change in celebration of Friday's SCOTUS decision.

Comment: I wouldn't say this answer is **hugely disappointing**, but nevertheless it doesn't have a lot to do with my request (which - in all fairness - is a bit meta indeed). I explicitly stated that the discussion about "politicisation" is valid and important, but that what can be gained from it - whoever "wins" or "loses" - is a logo better reflecting the site's traits. I never mentioned the Supreme Court once, and I do think that whatever is left as friction surface can be either dislike of the colour scheme (again, for whatever reason), or pragmatic reasons against a logo change in general.

Comment: As explained, IMO you are playing games - you've found  a (not so ) clever  good way to mask your political agenda in generic trappings.

Comment: @DeerHunter - not sure what you're trying to say, but "Ideologues" and "assault" are the appropriate terms in this context, since the whole rainbow logo idea is inappropriate and out of context on this site.

Comment: @Vector: DeerHunter was marking typos. And I'd accept a different colour scheme anytime. The point I was trying to make was that there's something to be gained from such a fruitful discussion. Not a very elaborate agenda, if any at all ...

Comment: @DeerHunter - fixed. Tnx.

Comment: re your [revision 5](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/298078/5). No: not a coincidence, as explicitly stated in section "Background" ("Inspired by"). And **of course** diversity is diversity, including different religious backgrounds (and how'd they get in here in the first place). But how can a colour scheme be "exclusionary"? And does the whole "tolerance towards the intolerant" discussion belong here? I don't think so.

Comment: @s.d a colour scheme is not exclusionary in itself, but what this specific icon and it's purpose represents is.

Comment: You're not being excluded from anything. What rights did you have before that you don't have now?

Comment: @BilltheLizard -  The logo is not granting or recinding anybody's rights. The question is regarding what/who it represents. You've missed the point....

Comment: There are plenty of Christians and Muslims around the world joining in celebrating the court's decision. Nobody's trying to exclude religion, they're just trying to move past a specific oppressive belief that's become unacceptable in civilized society.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - so what? There are also plenty who are **not**. You've added nothing here.

Comment: I think you're the one missing the point. Anyone who's not celebrating is choosing not to celebrate. They're not having that forced upon them. They're not being excluded by another group. They're perfectly welcome to do as they choose.

Comment: Vector, I suspect the downvotes here are not for your opposition to the SCOTUS ruling but the manner in which you have expressed it. People disagree with you, and that should be not only allowed, but treated with respect. Your opponents are not insulting you, nor advancing a secret agenda, nor assaulting your rights. I'm in favour of the SCOTUS decision (too narrow for my liking though!) but I didn't read the OP as a request to promote gay rights symbols/colours permanently. I would be surprised if the old logo is not restored anyway, so let's keep a sense of perspective.

Comment: Regarding @Jeremy's comment, I just found [a Christian celebrating Pride](https://plus.google.com/+JonSkeet/posts/R2qfffbDwW2). I think this stuff is worth pointing out.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - No. Not celebrating is neutral - passive. Celebrating is a statement and an activity. If some celebrates an event in the face of someone else who doesn't believe it worthy of celebration, they are taking an offensive **action.**

Comment: @halfer - 1) As I mentioned in my answer, I am not naive enough to believe that this suggestion should be taken at face value. If people downvote because they think I'm cynical, so be it. I'm not here to win friends and influence people, but to voice an opinion.  2) I expressed no personal opinion about the ruling whatsoever, in this or in any of my posts on this subject. Personally, I'm rather neutral about it. I simply objected to using the site as platform to celebrate it. **Is there now no sanctuary whatsoever from the endless din of political drumbeating?**

Comment: @Vector: I don't know why people downvoted you, and we can only guess. My view is that it is not your cynicism, but that you did not treat people with respect. You've called your opponents sly and underhand, and implied, I think, that unseen forces are conspiring to "push the gay agenda" permanently. As far as I can make out from the original post, the suggestion that we should be left with a colourful logo really _ought_ to be taken at face value, and anything more than that is on a par with demanding to see Obama's birth certificate.

Comment: FWIW I think the SCOTUS decision was the right one. I think the temporary logo change was a very positive thing, but also that it would be surprising for Stack Overflow to permanently change its brand identity at this point. If I were given the choice, I would vote for the switch back to the usual colours (which of course has now happened anyway).

Comment: I don't know if my observations are of any use to you - my style of interaction is quite philosophical, and I tend to prefer collaborative thinking rather than adversarial debate - but I wonder if your interaction style might be alienating people. I can say with all honesty that I point this out to be helpful - it is an genuine third-party assessment. Related to this, you seem to be holding a view incredibly strongly for someone who professes to be "rather neutral". That in turn might be something to ponder and meditate upon, possibly?

Comment: @halfer - If I need advice, I'll ask for it. :) Did you not understand my comment to you?

Comment: @Vector: isn't the risk of coming to Meta to **participate** in discussion that someone might give you their opinion?

Comment: (Re your edit: I'll happily clarify something if you like. What comment to me did I perhaps misunderstand? I earnestly would like to understand your views).