# Alert me when the fun starts!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I would like some kind of notification when a good question gets started on meta.

When I noticed that I just had missed [this wonderful party](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow), I was devastated. You see I didn't get to mention that 'there is no scientific proof on getting married makes you love your partner more' or 'now gay marriage is legalized, how about we keep the love and ban gay divorce'?

I am attracted to ... ~cough~ ... excellent questions like a hungry piranha to the fresh blood. When there is a flock, I want to be there!

Deep down I know many people feel the same way too. Therefore shall I suggest we have a option to sign on to the interesting questions that attracted  a) a lot of votes or b) extraordinary amount of traffic/views or c) huge amount of comments in the past hour?

Comment: There's already the "Featured on Meta" panel at the right side. Not a notification but definitely visible. Being aware of a "good question" in advance it's kind of impossible.. until it starts getting upvoted

Comment: It was featured at 17 votes, or within 30 minutes,

Comment: Featured would normally fit the criteria, but it does not mean all the questions fit the criteria get featured. @MarcoA. Real time notification would be a nice feature to have, without having to write a script doing the search all the times ...

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/6323/script-request-meta-notifications

Comment: "Deep down I know many people feel the same way" is probably not the most persuasive argument you've ever deployed.

Comment: The things you wanted to mention would have been way off the topic. Just look for a friendly bar, or locate some chatroom somewhere.

Comment: ITT kitties do not know how to RSS

Answer (score 13):

Those questions are typically popular. So, you can go to the popular tab:

- for new nav: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?show=alltime&tagFilter=all&tab=popular
- most close alternatives from the old nav: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=month or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot

Also, big events are typically featured, so look at the sidebar.

Another ways: make use of `score:X` or `views:X` search rules. Combine them with searching for words `unicorn*`, `fun*`, `waffle*`, `pon*` (for pony or ponies maybe), etc.

Comment: Even better, unicorn is mentioned 4 times in my post!. Wise words here.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) could be used to notify you about popular questions: it would take a sample of top upvoted questions every hour, and email you when it hits a predefined limit.

I should think this is REST-based, so you can use any programming language you like.

Comment: Best answer for programmers, imho.