# Do we actually need to have a [status-yay]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, meta

Let me keep it short, with the [featured question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297859/2173917) for [#LoveOverflows](https://twitter.com/hashtag/LoveOverflows?src=hash) , I saw the appearance of this tag [status-yay](/questions/tagged/status-yay).

When we see the description:

> Yay! This tag is for celebrating major historical events of importance to the Stack Exchange community.

I personally feel there is no need for this tag. `historical events of importance` are most likely to be featured on Meta, anyway. A tag, separately for this, is going to be very very *underused* (if not *unused*).

Presence of this tag may, also directly or indirectly encourage people to mis-tag question, which may not be actual purpose of the tag. Another series of debate will start, of events being "historical" or not which can be completely avoided by removing this tag.

**TL;DR** - We shall <del>Nuke</del> remove [status-yay](/questions/tagged/status-yay).

Above was my personal opinion, I humbly seek the opinion from all.

Comment: I was of the impression that the tag was simply being used in lieu of [status-completed] which prevented the post from showing up on the community bulletin, and would go away after this occasion. Apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: @BillWoodger Well, 1) the "about" for the tag says nothing about it. 2) this looks same as the normal tags, whereas the "mod-only" tags have different visual appearance. Did I miss anything there? Thanks. :-)

Comment: @BoltClock So, at least, my observation is correct, right? Let's hear what the community has to say about it. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed the tag wiki until you brought it up, so now you have me curious about the whole thing.

Comment: To be clear, that tag wiki was created by a [random user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/297902/revisions), not by an Stack Exchange employee. I was under the same impression as BoltClock, that the tag was going to exist only until this #LoveOverflow thing has blown over.

Comment: I confess, I added the tag wiki as a joke when I saw @AnnaLear had added the tag to the LoveOverflow question. I was wondering how long it would take someone to notice. Feel free to get rid of it.

Comment: @durron597 Appreciate your effort, but as I mentioned, IMHO, this can be problematic in future, so I proposed to remove it. Hope you understand my point. Thanks for showing up and the comment. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Well, it's good you made the meta post, because it can only be removed by a diamond as that featured question is locked now.

Comment: It was added by a dev, so I think it should probably stay - maybe ask her?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Do we actually need to have a [status-yay]?

Oh boy, let's not. :)

BoltClock is correct - I replaced [status-completed] with it because [status-completed] interfered with the community bulletin and a tag edit was faster than fixing the CB display. There's absolutely no need to keep [status-yay] around.

Comment: Thanks Anna for the reply.

Comment: Just asking: Did you (or I, will) get a hat? @abbyhairboat modified _your answer_ on _my question_..... _(sorry, WB15 is tooooo far)...._